# How to type NOT \delta and NOT \ll

Tags: symbols

In proximity theory, we use `\delta` and `\ll` as binary relations on the power set of a set X.  How can one display NOT `\delta` or NOT `\ll` similar to how we can do `\not\in`.  Using `\not\delta` and `\not\ll` place the strike-through in bad positions over the `\delta` and `\ll`.

For NOT `\delta`, I am currently using

- `\!\!\not\!\delta`

For NOT `\ll`, I am using

- `\hskip 0.4mm \not \hskip -0.4mm \ll`

There are a few problems here.  Sometimes the placement of the "not" over the "delta" is a little off but it varies throughout the pages.  Also, at the end of the line, I may get the `\not` appearing at the end of the current line and the `\delta` appearing at the beginning of the next line.  I have not noticed this issue with my defininition of NOT `\ll`.

What is the best way to define these symbols?  How can one make sure that the "not" is on the same line as the "delta"?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I took the liberty of formatting your code; backticks make it look pretty.

Comment: @Matthew: I made it even prettier by replacing `\\!` with `\!` `:-)` (The `\\!` was caused by the backticks.)

Comment: @Matthew, @Hendrik: Thank you. I am new here and will try to format things better from now on.  :-)

Answer (score 27):

Just use Heiko Oberdiek's `centernot` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$a\centernot\ll b \centernot\Delta c$

$a\centernot\longrightarrow b$

$a\centernot{\xrightarrow{1234567}} b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are there any drawbacks to `\let\not\centernot`?

Comment: @Knorad: No, I guess. But you'd better `\let\oldnot\not` first.

Comment: There seems to be a lot more spacing around a `\centernot\delta` than a `\delta`.  Is there any way to make them uniform?

Comment: @Justin: `\centernot` makes the symbol to be a math relation. You can use `\mathord{\centernot\delta}` or simply `{\centernot\delta}` to get an ordinary symbol.

Comment: @Leo: Thank you. I had no idea there were differences between relations and symbols. I guess I should keep notdelta as relational and instead make delta a binary relation using `\mathbin{\delta}`

Comment: @JustinJStark Actually you should make delta a binary relation using `\mathrel{\delta}`.  `\mathbin` makes it a binary operation, not a relation.

Answer (score 15):

Leo Liu told you a great way to define the symbols; I'd like to explain the odd behaviour you observed.

> Sometimes the placement of the "not" over the "delta" is a little off but it varies throughout the pages.

The reason for this is that `\not` is a *relational* symbol, and TeX inserts a `\thickmuskip` between an ordinary and a relational symbol (which gives nice spacing). Now `\thickmuskip` usually is a skip of `5.0mu plus 5.0mu`, which means: It's at least 5 `mu` units wide, but it can *stretch* an additional 5 `mu` units, depending on how full the current line is.

For example, if you type `$a \!\!\not\!\delta b$`, then TeX puts this `\thickmuskip` before the `\not` symbol *and also before the* `\delta`. The stretchability of this latter skip causes the placement of the "not" over the "delta" to vary throughout the pages.

> Also, at the end of the line, I may get the `\not` appearing at the end of the current line and the `\delta` appearing at the beginning of the next line.

If a relational symbol (like `\not`) is followed by a skip like `\!` (or by an ordinary symbol), TeX allows a line break in between. (TeXnically this is achieved by putting a `\penalty 500`.)

> I have not noticed this issue with my defininition of NOT `\ll`.

The issue with the undesired line break can also happen with your definition of NOT `\ll`. The variation of the placement of the "not", however, does not happen: The reason is that *both* `\not` and `\ll` are relational symbols, and TeX doesn't put any space between two relational symbols.

Comment: That's very helpful (to me at least)!

Answer (score 5):

I think you want the macro `\mathrlap` to overlap the slash on the symbol you are negating:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\NOTDelta}{\!\!\not\!\Delta}
\newcommand{\NOTll}{\hskip 0.4mm \not \hskip -0.4mm \ll}
\newcommand{\notDelta}{\mathrel{\mathrlap{\not}\Delta}}
\newcommand{\notll}{\mathrel{\mathrlap{\;\;\not}\ll}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    A &\not\Delta B     & A &\not\ll B \\
    A &\NOTDelta  B     & A &\NOTll  B \\
    A &\notDelta  B     & A &\notll  B
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample code]

The `\mathrel` command spaces your symbol as if it were a binary relation.  Without it your symbols get pushed too close together.  And the `\mathrlap` command sets its contents in a box of width zero, with the rest overlapping to the right.

Comment: Actually, `\mathbin` is for binary operators. `\mathrel` is for relations.

Comment: Note that the spacing to the left of your `\notll` is not good.

Comment: @TH.: You are correct, sir!  I made that change.

Comment: @Hendrik: Hm...how does that happen?  I expected my `\notll` to have the same width as `\ll`.

Comment: you get an automatically added `\thickmuskip` _twice_: once from your `\mathrel`, and once from the `\ll`; I'm not sure _why_ this happens. You could use `{\ll}` and adjust the `\;\;` to correct it.