# \rightarrow^* flipped to the left?

Tags: math-mode, arrows

Is it possible to create something like `$\rightarrow^*$` only flipped to the left?

Someone suggested using `$\mathbin{{}^*\leftarrow}$` but this still doesn't give me the same spacing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `\mathrel` instead of `\mathbin` (the arrows are regarded as *relational* symbols), and enclose `\leftarrow` in braces as to "kill" the spacing around it: `$\mathrel{{}^*{\leftarrow}}$`.

[image]

As egreg remarks, one can also use `$\mathrel{^*}\leftarrow$` to get exactly the same spacing: The `{}` before `^` is actually not needed, and TeX doesn't add any space between the relational symbols `\mathrel{^*}` and `\leftarrow`. (The advantage of the first solution (with or without `{}`) is somehow: One can be sure that it works without the knowledge about spacing between relational symbols.)

Comment: TeX doesn't add space between relation symbols, so `\mathrel{^*}\leftarrow` produces the same result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for [reminding me](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14208/how-to-type-not-delta-and-not-ll/14214#14214), @egreg!