# position of the slash in hatted \slashed

Tags: symbols, positioning, stacking-symbols

So I want to denote the Dirac operator with a hat, and I tried both `\hat{\slashed{D}}` and `\slashed{\hat{D}}`: the first one has the $^$ rather distant to the $\slashed{D}$, while the second one has the slash much too to the left of the $D$, almost coincide the semi-vertical stroke of the letter $D$.

Is there any way to adjust the position of the hat or slash?

Comment: Related: [What's the most elegant way to obtain Dirac operators? (slash notation)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26523/5764)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just overlap the symbol with the hat with the slashed version of itself.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,slashed}
\newcommand\hatslashed[1]{{\hat{#1}\mathllap{\slashed{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
$\hat{\slashed{D}}$
$\slashed{\hat{D}}$
$\hatslashed{D}_{\hatslashed{D}_{\hatslashed{D}}}$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

You can use `\phantom` in the following way to prevent double striking the glyph, but AFAIK `\phantom` doesn't detect cramped style and shifts the hat to the right.

```
\newcommand\hatslashed[1]{{\hat{\phantom{#1}}\mathllap{\slashed{#1}}}}
```

Comment: Was working a stack, but I like your answer better (+1).  I note that you double-strike the `D`.  Interestingly, in an effort to avoid that, I found that using `\phantom{#1}` on either the `\hat` or the `\slashed` elements also caused distortion.  Thus, the overstrike proved the only reliable method.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you for your appreciation! I will ask in chat about that strange interference. I'm still interested in your `stackengine` solution, please post it. My upvote is yours `:-)`

Comment: Better recheck that phantom...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Hm. Why does `\phantom` shift the slash? Does `\phantom` change back to horizontal mode, instead of staying in math mode?

Comment: This `\newcommand\hatslashedB[1]{{\,\hat{\phantom{\!#1}}\mathllap{\slashed{#1}}}}` is closer to the overstriked solution, note the `\!` and `\,`.  By the way, the phantom is shifting the `\hat`, I think, not the slash.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I investigated the defintion of `\phantom` and found `\mathph@nt: macro:#1#2->\setbox \z@ \hbox {$\m@th #1{#2}$}\finph@nt` which changes to horizontal mode (`\hbox`) and then inside back to math mode. Maybe that is the source of the shift.

Answer (score 9):

Without character overlapping:

```
\documentclass[border=3,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,slashed}

\makeatletter
\def\pslashed#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname psla@\string#1\endcsname\relax
    {\mathpalette{\sla@/00}{\phantom{#1}}}%
  \else
    \csname psla@\string#1\endcsname
  \fi}
\def\declarepslashed#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \expandafter\def\csname psla@\string#5\endcsname{%
    #1{\mathpalette{\sla@{#2}{#3}{#4}}{\phantom{#5}}}}}
\makeatother
\declarepslashed{}{/}{.08}{0}{D}

\newcommand\hatslashed[1]{\mathrlap{\hat{#1}}\slashed{#1}}
\begin{document}
$\hat{D}$

$\slashed{D}$

$\hatslashed{D}_{\hatslashed{D}_{\hatslashed{D}}}$
\end{document}
```

I define a command `\pslashed` that mimicks `\slashed`, but over a phantom.

Why doesn't `\hat{\phantom{D}}` give a good result? Because `\hat` cannot get the font metric information about the character D, because it's over a box containing nothing. So we set the accented character (in `\mathrlap`) and then set the slash as if it were across a D.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the mystery.  I may have more questions...

Comment: Your solution was very much tailored to the particular problem at hand.  Maybe a question is a better forum than a comment, but is it possible to generalize `\phantom` to somehow contain vestigial font metric information of what was phantomed?  In a related question, is there such a thing as what I will call `\leavetrace{D}`, which prints nothing, but makes whatever follows next in the input stream think a `D` had just preceded it?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That's a very tough question: several operation in math mode are performed differently when the nucleus of a atom is a character or something else (a box, a skip, …). When you have a box rather than a character, the metric information has been lost: there is no “mathbox”, only `\hbox` and `\vbox` (`\vtop`, `\vcenter`).

Answer (score 2):

This turned out a lot more interesting as an exercise, than I anticipated.  In the first row of my answer, I give the basic elements we are working with, the D, the hatted D, and the slashed D.

Then, on the second line, I confirm the OP's observations that creating composite glyphs `\hat{\slashed{D}}` and `\slashed{\hat D}` cause distortions in the result.  That's not too surprising, I guess.

So I figured this was tailor-made for a stack, wherein I could superimpose two of the basic elements atop each other to achieve the result.  I first confirmed that the basic elements were all the same width, not augmented laterally in some way by the decoration.  Of course, I wanted to avoid, if possible, double-striking the letter `D`, so I used a `\phantom` of `D` in one of the two elements of the stack.  And I found, very surprisingly to myself, that the phantom distorted the results, as well.

*About this time, Henri posted his solution, far superior to my own approach, since it naturally scales with mathstyle (whereas I would have to add the apparatus of `scalerel` on top of my solution to achieve that).  I abandoned my solution, voted for Henri, and left him a comment of my `\phantom` observation.  But then he asked for the stackengine result, so I continue.*

The third line of my result shows those phantom results, with the hat being shifted left in the first, and the stroke being shifted left in the second.  I figured it might have something to do with letter-specific kerns, lost with the phantom.

So, on the fourth line, I just lived with the double-striked `D`, same as Henri.  But, this approach does not, in its current form, scale with the mathstyle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\stackslashA#1#2{\def\stacktype{L}\stackon[0pt]{$#1{\phantom{#2}}$}{$\slashed{#2}$}}
\def\stackslashB#1#2{\def\stacktype{L}\stackon[0pt]{$#1{#2}$}{$\slashed{\phantom{#2}}$}}
\def\stackslash#1#2{\def\stacktype{L}\stackon[0pt]{$#1{#2}$}{$\slashed{#2}$}}
\begin{document}
Basic Elements: $D \hat D \slashed D $

Derived Elements:$\hat{\slashed{D}} \slashed{\hat D}$ (ugh!)

Stacked Phantoms: $\stackslashA{\hat}{D} \stackslashB{\hat}{D}$ (slight shifts)

Stacked Element: $\stackslash{\hat}{D}$ (double-stroked D)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `\phantom` inside the accent, here `\hat`, but not inside `\slashed`. Maybe you want to include this to prevent double striking.

Comment: @HenriMenke I'm sorry, but `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{slashed, mathtools}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\hatslashedA[1]{{\hat{\phantom{#1}}\mathllap{\slashed{#1}}}}
\newcommand\hatslashed[1]{{\hat{#1}\mathllap{\slashed{#1}}}}
$\hatslashedA{D}  \hatslashed{D}$
\end{document}` does not produce identical results.

Comment: @HenriMenke  As a follow up, the phantom version is horizontally off by (approximately) a `\!`