# How can I typeset this equation (standard model of physics)?

Tags: symbols, amsmath

So, there's this picture [image: lagrangian]

Floating around on the internet for the standard model of physics in a relatively short form. I want to typeset this in LaTeX in order to print it. However, I can't find a way to typeset the crossed out `D` in the second line.

So far, I have this

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} 

    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

    \begin{document}
    What part of

    \begin{align*}
    \mathcal{L} &= - \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} \\
        &+ i \bar{\psi} D \psi + h.c. \\
        &+ \bar{\psi}_i y_{ij} \psi_j \phi + h.c. \\
        &+ |D_\mu \phi|^2 - V(\phi)
    \end{align*}

    didn't you understand?

    \end{document}
```

Comment: I think the marked duplicate is wrong. The correct duplicate should rather be [What's the most elegant way to obtain Dirac operators? (slash notation)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26523/82917).

Comment: Note that [the first h.c. is an error and should be deleted](https://www.quantumdiaries.org/2011/06/26/cern-mug-summarizes-standard-model-but-is-off-by-a-factor-of-2/).

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory_(mathematics)#Dictionary_of_mathematical_and_physical_terminology) uses "[{D\!\!\!\!/}_{A}](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/b4c4aa492eff369e0e2f890174c38f656a0fba3e)'' -> \displaystyle{{D\!\!\!\!/}_{A}} which is quite artificial, but the angle is better for the crossing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `cancel` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,cancel}

\begin{document}
What part of

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L} &= - \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} \\
    &\phantom{{}=}+ i \bar{\psi} \cancel{D} \psi + h.c. \\
    &\phantom{{}=}+ \bar{\psi}_i y_{ij} \psi_j \phi + h.c. \\
    &\phantom{{}=}+ |D_\mu \phi|^2 - V(\phi)
\end{align*}

didn't you understand?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: seems like the easiest way to do this. thanks a lot!

Comment: To obtain more even row spacing, one might use `\tfrac` instead of `\frac` in the first row.

Comment: Just a remark, D should not be in italics.