# How do I draw a $\partial$ with a diagonal line through it?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

As the title suggests, how do I draw a `$\partial$` with a diagonal line through it?

Comment: Do you mean slashed like in quantum field theory?  If so, then have a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26523).

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for an eth ð? This isn't a `\partial` with a line through it, but there is the `\eth` command available with `amssymb` or there's the `\dh` command if you use T1 fonts. Or you can simply use XeTeX and use a font which contains the symbol

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001)

Answer (score 23):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{slashed}
\begin{document}
$\partial\kern-0.5em\raise0.22ex\hbox{/}$ or $\slashed{\partial}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: As one working in qft this is the one I prefer due to its simplicity

Answer (score 14):

A variation of `\centernot` (the slash needs to be raised a bit):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\npartial}{{%
  \mathpalette\raisenot\partial
}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\raisenot}[2]{%
  \raise.4\fontdimen22
    \ifx#1\displaystyle
      \textfont2
    \else
      \ifx#1\textstyle
        \textfont2
      \else
        \ifx#1\scriptstyle
          \scriptfont2
        \else
          \scriptscriptfont2
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
    \rlap{%
    \settowidth\dimen@{$\m@th#1{#2}$}%
    \kern.5\dimen@
    \settowidth\dimen@{$\m@th#1=$}%
    \kern-.5\dimen@
    $\m@th#1\not$%
  }%
  {#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\npartial A_{\npartial_{\npartial}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The [cancel package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cancel) provides a way of cancelling symbols (see the [cancel tag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cancel))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
$\cancel\partial$
\end{document}
```

Which yields

[image: \cancel\partial]

Comment: Though this is visually correct it does not have the correct semantics.  The slash in this case does not mean “cancel”, see [Feynman Slash Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_slash_notation).

Comment: @HenriMenke I just answered the question: a $\partial$ with a diagonal line through it.  Whether or not it has the correct semantics is a matter of interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

As a `\stackinset`.  Made to obey the math style.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel} 
\def\slashpartial{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\SavedStyle/}{%
  \SavedStyle\partial}}}}
\begin{document} 
\[
\slashpartial B\textstyle\slashpartial A_{\slashpartial_{\slashpartial}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is a version that only presents as the height of `\partial`.  Note it affects vertical height of subscripting.  I also tweaked the relative location 
of the slash by a fraction of a point:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel} 
\def\slashpartial{\vphantom{\partial}\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{\smash{%
  \stackinset{c}{.2\LMpt}{c}{-.2\LMpt}{\SavedStyle/}{\SavedStyle\partial}}}}}
\begin{document} 
\[
\slashpartial B\textstyle\slashpartial A_{\slashpartial_{\slashpartial}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some times this slashed notation (in physics) is called "Feynman slash". I use it very often. For that I use the `centernot` package, and define a command `\fy`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{centernot}
\newcommand\fy[1][\partial]{\centernot{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \fy \fy[A] \fy[p]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This yield 
[image]

However, after reading other answers I tried the package `slashed`,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{slashed}
\newcommand\fy[1][\partial]{\slashed{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \fy \fy[A] \fy[p]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

And the result seems improved,
[image]

Now you have another idea!