# Slashed partial derivative sign with blackboard bold

Tags: amsmath, blackboard

The last time I asked about [blackboard bold greek letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562884/blackboard-bold-greek-letters) and the answers given opened up to me a new world of possibilities.
So I'm just having fun with `\mathb` command (that is exactly the `\mathbb` defined in the main answer, just renamed that way to still be able to use the original `\mathbb`), using it with every sign that should represent a matrix; for example I'm using `$\slashed{\mathb{p}}$` instead of the usual `$\slashed{p}$` in the Dirac slashed notation ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26523/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-obtain-dirac-operators-slash-notation) a question about the way to write the slash)

But I have a problem: now I want to write `$\slashed{\mathb{\partial}}$` but this error message appears

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> \partial 
l.20142 $\slashed{\mathb{\partial}}$
```

What can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a manual way to do it...save the intermediate result in a box and apply `\slashed` to the box.  The trick now is to redefine `\mathb` to have this way, perhaps, as the default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,slashed}
\input pdf-trans
\newbox\qbox
\def\usecolor#1{\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname\space}
\newcommand\bordercolor[1]{\colsplit{1}{#1}}
\newcommand\fillcolor[1]{\colsplit{0}{#1}}
\newcommand\outline[1]{\leavevmode%
  \def\maltext{#1}%
  \setbox\qbox=\hbox{\maltext}%
  \boxgs{Q q 2 Tr \bbthickness\space w \fillcol\space \bordercol\space}{}%
  \copy\qbox%
}
\newcommand\mathb[1]{\outline{$#1$}}
\newcommand\textbb[1]{\outline{#1}}
\newcommand\colsplit[2]{\colorlet{tmpcolor}{#2}\edef\tmp{\usecolor{tmpcolor}}%
  \def\tmpB{}\expandafter\colsplithelp\tmp\relax%
  \ifnum0=#1\relax\edef\fillcol{\tmpB}\else\edef\bordercol{\tmpC}\fi}
\def\colsplithelp#1#2 #3\relax{%
  \edef\tmpB{\tmpB#1#2 }%
  \ifnum `#1>`9\relax\def\tmpC{#3}\else\colsplithelp#3\relax\fi
}
\bordercolor{black}
\fillcolor{white}
\newcommand\bbthickness{.15}
\begin{document}
$\sbox0{$\mathb{\partial}$} \slashed{\copy0}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Now I would have stayed one million years to do it ahah Thanks a lot

Comment: @Rob I am agree with your comment :-)

Comment: Just a very basic question. With commands like '\tensor' (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tensor) I can do '\tensor{A}{^a_b}', but I theoretically cannot do '\tensor{A_1}{^a_b}' due to the subscript '_1' following 'A'; but I cheat on this and I write '\tensor{{A_1}}{^a_b}' and so the added curly brakets create like a "box" inside which there is 'A_1' and now the command works! Why I cannot do the same with '\slashed'? So in this case something like '\slashed{{\mathb{\partial}}}' wouldn't work.

Comment: @Rob Every macro has it's own way of performing it's magic.  Sometimes, a group is sufficient to overcome a problem, sometimes not.  However, a group `{}` is not the same thing as a box.

Comment: Ok thank you I didn't know the difference