# Cleanest implementation for Unicode U+2AEC (Double-Stroke Not Sign) using overlapping \lnot's?

Tags: symbols

I'm using the Unicode character "Double-Stroke Not Sign" (U+2AEC) to represent bitwise logical not operation (a.k.a. one's complement).  I've implemented a control sequence called `\blnot` which accomplishes this, but my solution feels kludgey and I suspect there must be a best-practices solution which is much cleaner.  Here is how my output looks with `$-$`, `\lnot`, and `\blnot`, respectively:

[image: blnot sample]

My question is two parts:

1. What is the cleanest way to stack two `\lnot` operators as shown above? I made an `\hbox` and used `\raisebox` to adjust the base of each instance, but I don't like how I used `\kern-.666666em` to back up 2/3 em after the first instance. I feel like there should be a way to cleanly go back the exact width of `\lnot` without having to know it, or better yet simply to not advance at all between the two.
2. I would also like to insert approximately .11em after both `\lnot` and `\blnot` because it looks too tight otherwise. (I'll be using `\blnot` mostly with multi-character identifiers in italics.) I've added the space this by saying `\kern.11em`, but again that feels kludgey to me.  Ideally, I'd like to inuit the width of `$-$` and simply use that, without hard-coding any width.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\blnot}{
  \mathord{%
    \hbox{%
      \raisebox{.19ex}{$\lnot$}\kern-.666666em%
      \raisebox{-.21ex}{$\lnot$}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
$-a$                  \vskip -1ex
$\lnot\kern.11em a$   \vskip -1ex
$\blnot\kern.11em a$  \par
\end{document}
```

p.s. I know I could easily implement this using TikZ, but stacking two `\lnot`s seems easier to make work at multiple font sizes. (I won't probably be using this at any size other than 10pt, but I might use it in a footnote or a caption.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for `\ooalign`:

```
\newcommand{\blnot}{\mathord{\ooalign{%
  \relax\cr
  \noalign{\vskip-.2ex}
  $\lnot$\cr
  \noalign{\vskip.4ex}
  $\lnot$\cr
  \noalign{\vskip-.2ex}}%
  }}
```

Here's a complete example, where the `\fbox` show the effect on the bounding box; the first is `\lnot`, the second my proposed definition, the third is from Todd Lehman's self answer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\blnot}{\mathord{\ooalign{%
  \relax\cr
  \noalign{\vskip-.2ex}
  $\lnot$\cr
  \noalign{\vskip.4ex}
  $\lnot$\cr
  \noalign{\vskip-.2ex}}%
  }}

\newcommand{\TLblnot}{
  \mathord{%
    \hbox{%
      \raisebox{.18ex}{\rlap{$\lnot$}}%
      \raisebox{-.22ex}{\rlap{$\lnot$}}%
      \hphantom{$-$}%
    }%
  }%
}\begin{document}
\fbox{$\lnot a$}\fbox{$\blnot a$}\fbox{$\TLblnot a$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a size changing symbol, you can do the more complicated

```
\newcommand{\blnot}{\mathord{\mathpalette\xblnot\relax}}

\newcommand{\xblnot}[2]{
  \sbox2{$#1\lnot$}\vrule height 1.1\ht2 width0pt \ooalign{%
  \relax\cr
  \noalign{\vskip-.2\ht2}
  $#1\lnot$\cr
  \noalign{\vskip.4\ht2}
  $#1\lnot$\cr
  \noalign{\vskip-.2\ht2}}%
  }
```

and here's the result of

```
\fbox{$\lnot$}\fbox{$\blnot$}\fbox{$\blnot_{\blnot_{\blnot}}$}
```

[image]

It's quite simple also to get the symbol's bounding box as wide as a minus sign:

```
\newcommand{\blnot}{\mathord{\mathpalette\xblnot\relax}}

\newcommand{\xblnot}[2]{
  \sbox2{$#1\lnot$}\vrule height 1.1\ht2 width0pt \ooalign{%
  \hphantom{$#1-$}\relax\cr
  \noalign{\vskip-.2\ht2}
  \hfil$#1\lnot$\hfil\cr
  \noalign{\vskip.4\ht2}
  \hfil$#1\lnot$\hfil\cr
  \noalign{\vskip-.2\ht2}}%
  }
```

Some information on `\ooalign` can be found [in this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/4427)

Comment: This is cool. A couple follow-up questions: (1) How best then to ensure a width equal to `$-$`? Wrap the `\ooalign` inside an `\hbox` with `\rlap` and `\hphantom`? I did that, and it seemed to work great. (2) Is there a good tutorial on `\ooalign`? I did some web searches and only turned up obscure examples. (3) The fact that the bounding box is larger than necessary in my version...is that actually a problem? It doesn't seem to be problematic unless the upper `\lnot` is raised about 1.2ex higher.

Comment: @ToddLehman See edit

Comment: I see what you're saying about the size changes, @egreg. My `\hbox` was clobbering the super/sub-script sizes. It worked fine when I did `\scriptsize`, but it fails, as you point out, in actual superscripts and subscripts. I probably won't be using this symbol in superscripts or subscripts, but it's really nice to see an example of how to make that work. I didn't know about `\mathpalette`, although I have a tiny bit of experience with `\mathchoice`. I'll read up on `\mathpalette` tomorrow so I can understand what is going on under the hood here. :)

Comment: Hey @egreg, I'm really liking this `\ooalign`. I just modified one of my other stacking symbol commands to use it where my bounding boxes had been slightly a bit too tall, causing a bit of unwanted space between lines. But now, with `\ooalign`, the line spacing is constant even if I stack a symbol so high that it protrudes all the way up into the line above it.  (Not that I would do that for real, but I tested it that way just to be sure.) Nifty.

Comment: p.s. I marked your answer as my accepted answer. I was really happy with the `\rlap` solution earlier, but your `\ooalign` solution seems a safer way to go, and a better habit to get into for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

(Answering my own question here.) I ended up solving this myself, after [Mikael Vejdemo-Johansson](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/257/mikael-vejdemo-johansson) recommended that I use `\llap` or `\rlap`. Here's what I did.  I am very happy with this solution:

```
\newcommand{\blnot}{
  \mathord{%
    \hbox{%
      \raisebox{.18ex}{\rlap{$\lnot$}}%
      \raisebox{-.22ex}{\rlap{$\lnot$}}%
      \hphantom{$-$}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

But taking it one step further, I defined it in terms of a `\stacktwo` command (for lack of a better name) that takes five parameters...

1. First character (e.g., `\lnot`)
2. Distance to raise first character (e.g., `.18ex`)
3. Second character (e.g., `\lnot`)
4. Distance to raise second character (e.g., `-.22ex`)
5. Phantom character to define width of composite character sequence (e.g., $-$)

...and goes like this:

```
\newcommand{\stacktwo}[5]{%
  \mathord{%
    \hbox{%
      \raisebox{#2}{\rlap{#1}}%
      \raisebox{#4}{\rlap{#3}}%
      \hphantom{#5}%
    }
  }
}
```

The final definition then is very simple:

```
\newcommand{\xblnot}{\stacktwo{$\lnot$}{.18ex}{$\lnot$}{-.22ex}{$-$}}
```

This does exactly what I want for all of `\normalsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\scriptsize`, and `\tiny`, and I can re-use `\stacktwo` for other composites like Unicode character U+2A59 ("Logical Or Overlapping Logical And").

A minor flaw here is that the widths of the two characters must be exactly the same, because I haven't yet figured out how to vertically align two stacked items of different widths, but this solution works fine for the characters I need.

Comment: What would be a better name here than `\stacktwo`? It's more "overlapping" than it is "stacking." Need some name that means "overlap two non-advancing characters at different heights and then advance by the phantom width of a third character."

Comment: What about `\verticalcombine`? Or maybe shorter, `\vcombine`?

Comment: I like `\vcombine`, @celtschk. Thank you. Voted your comment up. :)

Answer (score 2):

This forum thread:
https://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/8ed2ea2326858f8f?pli=1
provides several suggestions on how to implement a negative `\phantom` command which would allow you to step backwards with exactly your symbol's width.

In particular, this thread points out the LaTeX commands `\llap` and `\rlap`, both built to allow the construction of complex shapes by overlapping glyphs with sensible alignment. The example given is a construction of ≠ by either of the commands `/\llap{=}` or `\rlap{=}/`.

Thus, for your case, it would seem as if `\rlap{\raisebox{-0.21em}{\lnot}}\raisebox{0.19em}{\lnot}` might work.

Comment: Oooh. Excellent. I will check those out. I may devise a general control sequence that combines the the `\rlap` with the raising/lowering.

Comment: Mikael, that worked great. It wasn't easy for me, as I hadn't used `\rlap` before, but I figured it out with some experimentation. I posted my solution as an answer. Is that what you had in mind? I was very pleasantly surprised to see that a double use of `\rlap` makes it possible to use `\hphantom{$-$}` to define the width.