# Specific tikz shape with parameters

Tags: tikz-pgf

The idea is to define several shapes useful for example in control schemes.

For example a generic shape for conversion could be defined instead of creating one shape for each conversion.

[image: Shape created]

The code corresponding to the previous picture was achieved with

```
\documentclass[tikz]{minimal}

\def\alphabetatodq{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[rounded corners=5pt] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \draw (0.1,0.1) -- (.9,.9);
  \node at (0.25,0.8) {$\alpha\beta$};
  \node at (0.75,0.2) {dq};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) {\alphabetatodq};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Another requirement is after my test with the \def stuff, it leads to white spaces around the shape when trying to connect it.

[image: Arrows connexion]

The code is

```
\documentclass[tikz]{minimal}

\def\alphabetatodq{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[rounded corners=5pt] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \draw (0.1,0.1) -- (.9,.9);
  \node at (0.25,0.8) {$\alpha\beta$};
  \node at (0.75,0.2) {dq};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) at (0,0) {\alphabetatodq};
  \draw (-2,0) -- (a) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

All this would be nice if the concept can be extended to shape without inner parametric content.

---

A small hack like this shows the white surrounding spacing problem

```
\documentclass[tikz]{minimal}
\def\alphabetatodq{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[rounded corners=5pt] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
      \draw (0.1,0.1) -- (.9,.9);
      \node at (0.25,0.8) {$\alpha\beta$};
      \node at (0.75,0.2) {dq};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,rounded corners=5pt] (a) at (0,0) {\dctoac};
  \draw (-2,0) -- (a) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Hack]

Comment: You can modify the definition of the `circle solidus` shape from `shapes.multipart` library. That would be a genuine node shape so you don't need to nest TikZ pictures.

Comment: Could you develop this a bit more ? I don't get it.

Comment: You can also use the `late options` like `append after command`; a couple of references: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98289/13304 for the line and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106836/13304 for getting hints about the labels.

Comment: The “white surrounding spacing problem” is due the `inner sep` settings and (if the border is not drawn) the `outer sep` settings.

Comment: Nice fix Qrrbrbirlbel.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution via `append after command` and `pgfinterruptpath`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset {
  convert/.style 2 args={
    minimum size=1cm,
    rounded corners=5pt,
    append after command={
      \pgfextra{
        \pgfinterruptpath
        \path (\tikzlastnode.north west)
        node[inner sep=2pt,anchor=north west]{#1};
        \path (\tikzlastnode.south east)
        node[inner sep=2pt,anchor=south east]{#2};
        \draw ([shift={(1mm, 1mm)}]\tikzlastnode.south west)
        -- ([shift={(-1mm, -1mm)}]\tikzlastnode.north east);
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      }
    },
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,convert={DC}{AC}] (a) at (0,2) {};
  \node[draw,convert={$\alpha\beta$}{dq}] (b) at (2,2) {};
  \draw (-2,2) -- (a) -- (b) -- (4,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a shape called `split rectangle with rounded corners`. It actually supports different radii for every corner with the keys

- `/pgf/rectangle with rounded corners north west radius`,
- `/pgf/rectangle with rounded corners north east radius`,
- `/pgf/rectangle with rounded corners south west radius`, and
- `/pgf/rectangle with rounded corners south east radius`.

The key `/pgf/rectangle with rounded corners radius` to set all radii to the same length.

It is probably not the most efficient way to define that shape but it takes the `outer sep`arators into consideration.

However, it does *not* support different outer separators. It also *doesn’t check* whether the radii for the corners are not too big. It does not take the line width of the diagonal line into consideration, hopefully this is not a problem in most cases.

The diagonal line will always have an angle of 45° relatively to the node. The node parts and the line will be enclosed in a square. This square will always stretch (if `minimum width`/`minimum height` are greater than the possible smallest square).

The PGF library `intersection` is needed to find the shape border for the part of the rounded corners.

As the code is rather huge, I don’t post it in this answer but it is available at [`tikzlibraryshapes.qrr.roundedrectangle.code.tex`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibraryshapes.qrr.roundedrectangle.code.tex).
Use `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.qrr.roundedrectangle}` to load.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.qrr.roundedrectangle}
\tikzset{
  shape example/.style={
    color=black!30,
    draw,
    fill=yellow!30,
    line width=.5cm,
    inner xsep=2.5cm,
    inner ysep=0.5cm}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
  draw,
  split rectangle with rounded corners,
  rectangle with rounded corners radius=5pt,
  line cap=round,
  minimum size=1cm
] (n) {$\alpha\beta$ \nodepart{lower} dq};
\foreach \Angle in {0,2.5,...,359} \draw (\Angle:1) -- (n);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}\Huge
  \node[draw,split rectangle with rounded corners,shape example,rectangle with rounded corners radius=50pt] (n) {\TeX t \nodepart{lower} more \TeX t};
  \foreach \Pos/\Anchor/\Text in {left/below north west,above right/right north west,
                                  above left/left north east,right/below north east,
                                  right/above south east,below left/left south east,
                                  below right/right south west,left/above south west}
    \draw[thin] plot[mark=x,only marks] coordinates {
    (n.\Anchor)} node[\Pos,text depth=+0pt,text height=+3pt] {\tiny\ttfamily\Text};

  \foreach \Pos/\Anchor/\Text in {above/center,above/north,left/west,right/east,below/south,
                                  above left/north west,below left/south west,
                                  below right/south east,above right/north east}
    \draw[thin] plot[mark=x,only marks] coordinates {
      (n.\Anchor)} node[\Pos,text depth=+0pt,text height=+3pt] {\tiny\ttfamily\Text};

  \foreach \Pos/\Anchor/\Text in {above left/mid west,above right/mid east,above/mid,
                                  left/base west,right/base east,
                                  below/base,below/text,below/lower}
    \draw[thin] plot[mark=x,only marks] coordinates {
      (n.\Anchor)} node[\Pos,text depth=+0pt,text height=+3pt] {\tiny\ttfamily\Text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a key to remove the line? In my case, I need to position text at the opposing diagonals of a rectangle, but sometimes without the line.  This was the only shape I was able to find that does the job. I assume I also have to save the file tikzlibraryshapes.qrr.roundedrectangle.code.tex to my tikzlibraryshapes directory, right? Thanks for any help.