# How `rotatebox` could be defined in plain TeX?

Tags: plain-tex, box

I was wondering if it is possible to define `rotatebox` in plain old TeX (without importing `eplain`, `pstricks`, `miniltx` or what not or using `pdfrotate` or other pdf-specific commands).

The word "rotate" does not seem to appear in the TeXbook and it only refers to `vbox` and `hbox`.

Use cases:

- Write the answers to an exercise upside down,
- create new mathematical symbols (e.g., `\newcommand{\diamondplus}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\boxtimes$}}` [overstruck \diamond and plus in plain TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44073/overstruck-diamond-and-plus-in-plain-tex))

If would be nice to have a macro for origin center, another one (or the same with a different argument) for origin top-left, etc. but just one will be a valid answer to help me understand how to do such things.

Comment: If you want reinvent the wheel: rotation is backend dependant. If you create a pdf you have e.g. to use `pdfsetmatrix` (see pdftex.def) and with dvips postscript instructions like `\special{ps: gsave currentpoint  currentpoint translate \Grot@angle\GPT@space neg
 rotate neg exch neg exch translate}` (see dvips.def). And naturally you need various commands to calculate the angle etc (see e.g graphics.sty). It is easier to reuse existing code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It is somewhat surprising that TeX does not have this natively, I don't want to reinvent the wheel, just to know how the first wheel was made

Comment: as ulrike says you need to implement sin and cos functions in tex macros (unless you just want to rotate by 90° which would cover 99% of use cases) and the insert different `\special` for each driver (dvips, dvipdfmx, dvisvg, ...) or back end primitive for pdftex or luatex

Comment: @Laravel The point here is basically what you observe: TeX itself can't do rotation, so we need to use backend-specific specials.

Answer (score 3):

I only filled in the backend code for `pdftex` the other branches of the conditionals at the end will need suitable `\Grot@start` definitions (from `graphics-def/luatex.def` etc)

But this works with `pdftex`

[image]

```
%package
\catcode`@=11

%latex.ltx
\def\zap@space#1 #2{%
  #1%
  \ifx#2\@empty\else\expandafter\zap@space\fi
  #2}
\def\@car#1#2\@nil{#1}
\def\@cdr#1#2\@nil{#2}
\def\@empty{}
\long\def\@gobble#1{}
\long\def\@firstofone#1{#1}

%trig.sty
\chardef\nin@ty=90
\chardef\@clxxx=180
\chardef\@lxxi=71
\mathchardef\@mmmmlxviii=4068
\chardef\@coeffz=72
\chardef\@coefb=42
\mathchardef\@coefc=840
\mathchardef\@coefd=5040
{\catcode`t=12\catcode`p=12\gdef\noPT#1pt{#1}}
\def\TG@rem@pt#1{\expandafter\noPT\the#1\space}
\def\TG@term#1{%
 \dimen@\@tempb\dimen@
 \advance\dimen@ #1\p@}
\def\TG@series{%
 \dimen@\@lxxi\dimen@
 \divide \dimen@ \@mmmmlxviii
 \edef\@tempa{\TG@rem@pt\dimen@}%
 \dimen@\@tempa\dimen@
 \edef\@tempb{\TG@rem@pt\dimen@}%
 \divide\dimen@\@coeffz
 \advance\dimen@\m@ne\p@
 \TG@term\@coefb
 \TG@term{-\@coefc}%
 \TG@term\@coefd
 \dimen@\@tempa\dimen@
 \divide\dimen@ \@coefd}
\def\CalculateSin#1{{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname sin(\number#1)\endcsname\relax
    \dimen@=#1\p@\TG@@sin
    \expandafter\xdef\csname sin(\number#1)\endcsname
                                    {\TG@rem@pt\dimen@}%
  \fi}}
\def\CalculateCos#1{{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname cos(\number#1)\endcsname\relax
    \dimen@=\nin@ty\p@
    \advance\dimen@-#1\p@
    \TG@@sin
    \expandafter\xdef\csname cos(\number#1)\endcsname
                                     {\TG@rem@pt\dimen@}%
  \fi}}
\def\TG@reduce#1#2{%
\dimen@#1#2\nin@ty\p@
  \advance\dimen@#2-\@clxxx\p@
  \dimen@-\dimen@
  \TG@@sin}
\def\TG@@sin{%
  \ifdim\TG@reduce>+%
  \else\ifdim\TG@reduce<-%
  \else\TG@series\fi\fi}%
\def\UseSin#1{\csname sin(\number#1)\endcsname}
\def\UseCos#1{\csname cos(\number#1)\endcsname}
\def\z@num{0 }
\def\@tempa{1 }
\def\@tempb{-1 }
\expandafter\let\csname sin(0)\endcsname\z@num
\expandafter\let\csname cos(0)\endcsname\@tempa
\expandafter\let\csname sin(90)\endcsname\@tempa
\expandafter\let\csname cos(90)\endcsname\z@num
\expandafter\let\csname sin(-90)\endcsname\@tempb
\expandafter\let\csname cos(-90)\endcsname\z@num


%graphics.sty
\newdimen\Grot@height
\newdimen\Grot@left
\newdimen\Grot@right
\newdimen\Grot@depth
\newdimen\Grot@l
\newdimen\Grot@r
\newdimen\Grot@h
\newdimen\Grot@d
\newdimen\Grot@x
\newdimen\Grot@y
\long\def\rotatebox#1#2{%
  \leavevmode
  \Grot@setangle{#1}%
  \setbox\z@\hbox{{#2}}%
  \Grot@x\z@
  \Grot@y\z@
  \Grot@box}
\def\Grot@setangle#1{\edef\Grot@angle{#1}}
\def\Grot@Px#1#2#3{%
        #1\Grot@cos#2%
        \advance#1-\Grot@sin#3}
\def\Grot@Py#1#2#3{%
        #1\Grot@sin#2%
        \advance#1\Grot@cos#3}
\def\Grot@box{%
  \begingroup
  \CalculateSin\Grot@angle
  \CalculateCos\Grot@angle
  \edef\Grot@sin{\UseSin\Grot@angle}%
  \edef\Grot@cos{\UseCos\Grot@angle}%
  \Grot@r\wd\z@  \advance\Grot@r-\Grot@x
  \Grot@l\z@     \advance\Grot@l-\Grot@x
  \Grot@h\ht\z@  \advance\Grot@h-\Grot@y
  \Grot@d-\dp\z@ \advance\Grot@d-\Grot@y
  \ifdim\Grot@sin\p@>\z@
    \ifdim\Grot@cos\p@>\z@
      \Grot@Py\Grot@height \Grot@r\Grot@h%B
      \Grot@Px\Grot@right  \Grot@r\Grot@d%E
      \Grot@Px\Grot@left   \Grot@l\Grot@h%C
      \Grot@Py\Grot@depth  \Grot@l\Grot@d%D
    \else
      \Grot@Py\Grot@height \Grot@r\Grot@d%E
      \Grot@Px\Grot@right  \Grot@l\Grot@d%D
      \Grot@Px\Grot@left   \Grot@r\Grot@h%B
      \Grot@Py\Grot@depth  \Grot@l\Grot@h%C
    \fi
  \else
    \ifdim\Grot@cos\p@<\z@
      \Grot@Py\Grot@height \Grot@l\Grot@d%D
      \Grot@Px\Grot@right  \Grot@l\Grot@h%C
      \Grot@Px\Grot@left   \Grot@r\Grot@d%E
      \Grot@Py\Grot@depth  \Grot@r\Grot@h%B
    \else
      \Grot@Py\Grot@height \Grot@l\Grot@h%C
      \Grot@Px\Grot@right  \Grot@r\Grot@h%B
      \Grot@Px\Grot@left   \Grot@l\Grot@d%D
      \Grot@Py\Grot@depth  \Grot@r\Grot@d%E
    \fi
  \fi
  \advance\Grot@height\Grot@y
  \advance\Grot@depth\Grot@y
  \Grot@Px\dimen@  \Grot@x\Grot@y
  \Grot@Py\dimen@ii \Grot@x\Grot@y
  \dimen@-\dimen@     \advance\dimen@-\Grot@left
  \dimen@ii-\dimen@ii \advance\dimen@ii\Grot@y
  \setbox\z@\hbox{%
    \kern\dimen@
    \raise\dimen@ii\hbox{\Grot@start\box\z@\Grot@end}}%
  \ht\z@\Grot@height
  \dp\z@-\Grot@depth
  \advance\Grot@right-\Grot@left\wd\z@\Grot@right
  \leavevmode\box\z@
  \endgroup}




\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
\else
\ifnum\pdfoutput=1
%pdftex.def
\def\GPT@space{ }
\def\GPT@MatrixIdentity{1 0 0 1}
\def\GPT@Zero{0}
\def\GPT@Minus{-}
\def\GPT@NormalizeNumber#1{%
  \edef#1{#1}%
  \edef#1{\expandafter\zap@space#1 \@empty}%
  \edef#1{\expandafter\GPT@ZapPlus#1+\@nil}%
  \edef#1{\expandafter\GPT@ZapMinusMinus#1--\@nil}%
  \expandafter\GPT@Split#1..\@nil
  \ifx\GPT@frac\@empty
  \else
    \edef\GPT@frac{%
      \expandafter\GPT@Reverse\expandafter{\expandafter}\GPT@frac\@nil
    }%
    \edef\GPT@frac{%
      \expandafter\GPT@ZapLeadingZeros\GPT@frac\@empty
    }%
    \ifx\GPT@frac\@empty
    \else
      \edef\GPT@frac{%
        \expandafter\GPT@Reverse\expandafter{\expandafter}\GPT@frac\@nil
      }%
    \fi
  \fi
  \edef\GPT@sign{\expandafter\@car\GPT@int\@empty\@nil}%
  \ifx\GPT@sign\GPT@Minus
    \edef\GPT@int{\expandafter\@cdr\GPT@int\@nil}%
  \else
    \def\GPT@sign{}%
  \fi
  \edef\GPT@int{%
    \expandafter\GPT@ZapLeadingZeros\GPT@int\@empty
  }%
  \edef\GPT@temp{\GPT@int\GPT@frac}%
  \ifx\GPT@temp\@empty
    \def#1{0}%
  \else
    \edef#1{%
      \GPT@sign
      \GPT@int
      \ifx\GPT@frac\@empty
      \else
        .\GPT@frac
      \fi
    }%
  \fi
}
\def\GPT@ZapPlus#1+#2\@nil{%
  #1%
  \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {%
    \GPT@ZapPlus#2\@nil
  }%
}
\def\GPT@ZapMinusMinus#1--#2\@nil{%
  #1%
  \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {%
    \GPT@ZapMinusMinus#2\@nil
  }%
}
\def\GPT@Split#1.#2.#3\@nil{%
  \def\GPT@int{#1}%
  \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
    \let\GPT@frac\@empty
  \else
    \def\GPT@frac{#2}%
  \fi
}
\def\GPT@Reverse#1#2#3\@nil{%
  \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
    #2#1%
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {%
    \GPT@Reverse{#2#1}#3\@nil
  }%
}
\def\GPT@ZapLeadingZeros#1{%
  \ifx0#1%
    \expandafter\GPT@ZapLeadingZeros
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}
\def\Grot@start{%
  \GPT@NormalizeNumber\Grot@sin
  \GPT@NormalizeNumber\Grot@cos
  \edef\GPT@temp{%
    \Grot@cos\GPT@space\Grot@sin\GPT@space
    \if-\Grot@sin
    \else
      \ifx\Grot@sin\GPT@Zero
        \GPT@Zero
      \else
        -\Grot@sin
      \fi
    \fi
    \GPT@space\Grot@cos
  }%
  \ifx\GPT@temp\GPT@MatrixIdentity
    \def\Grot@end{}%
  \else
    \pdfsave
    \pdfsetmatrix{\GPT@temp}%
    \wd\z@\z@
  \fi
}
\def\Grot@end{\pdfrestore}

\else
\fi
\fi


%end package
\catcode`@=12

% a plain tex document

aaa \rotatebox{45}{use La\TeX} bbb

\bye
```

Comment: I think that while this gives working code it doesn't explain what's the mechanism...? (assume you're happy with computing sin and cos "by hand" etc. what would the code be? Probably using pdfrestore pdfsave pdfsetmatrix?)

Comment: @user202729 _all_ that code is fully documented in the packages specified in comments. `texdoc trig` for example explains the trig calculation.

Answer (score 3):

I thing that most elementary implementation of rotating can be found in OPmac macros. It is based on `\pdfsetmatrix`, `\pdfsave`, `\pdfrestore` from `pdftex` but other engines can define these commands very simply, see `opmac-xetex.tex` file, for example.

The main problem is, ta we have to use `\pdfsetmatrix{cos\alpha sin\alpha -sin\alpha cos\alpha}`, it means that we must to implement a simple calculation of cos, sin, which is not present in the classical TeX. The implementation in the following OPmac macros does an interpolation of value of these functions using table of the values.

```
\newdimen\tmpdim \newcount\tmpnum

\def\pdfscale#1#2{\pdfsetmatrix{#1 0 0 #2}}

\def\pdfrotate#1{\tmpdim=#1pt
   \ifdim\tmpdim=0pt
   \else \ifdim\tmpdim=90pt \pdfsetmatrix{0 1 -1 0}%
         \else \edef\tmp{#1}\expandafter\pdfrotateA\tmp..\relax
   \fi   \fi
}
\def\pdfrotateA #1.#2.#3\relax{%
   \def\tmp##1.##2\relax {##1}%
   \tmpnum=\expandafter \tmp \the\tmpdim \relax % round
   \ifdim\tmpdim>0pt \def\tmpa{}\else\def\tmpa{-}\fi % save -
   \loop \ifnum\tmpnum<0 \advance\tmpnum by360 \repeat
   \loop \ifnum\tmpnum>360 \advance\tmpnum by-360 \repeat
   \loop \ifnum\tmpnum>90 \pdfrotate{90}\advance\tmpnum by-90 \repeat
   \ifnum\tmpnum=90 \pdfrotate{90}\else
      \ifnum\tmpnum>44 \pdfsetmatrix{.7071 .7071 -.7071 .7071}%
                       \advance\tmpnum by-45 \fi
      \ifnum\tmpnum>22 \pdfsetmatrix{.9272 .3746 -.3746 .9272}%
                       \advance\tmpnum by-22 \fi
      \ifnum\tmpnum>0
         \pdfsetmatrix{\smallcos \smallsin -\smallsin \smallcos}%
   \fi\fi
   \if$#2$\else % fraction part
      \tmpdim=.01745329pt % \pi/180
      \tmpdim=.#2\tmpdim  %
      \edef\tmp{\expandafter\ignorept\the\tmpdim\space}%
      \ifx\tmpa\empty \pdfsetmatrix{1 \tmp -\tmp 1}%
      \else           \pdfsetmatrix{1 -\tmp \tmp 1}%
   \fi\fi
}
\def\smallcos{.\ifcase\tmpnum \or9998\or9994\or9986\or9976\or9962\or9945\or
  9925\or9903\or9877\or9848\or9816\or9781\or9744\or9703\or9659\or9613\or
  9563\or9511\or9455\or9397\or9336\or9272\fi\space}
\def\smallsin{.\ifcase\tmpnum 0\or0175\or0359\or0523\or0698\or0872\or1045\or
  1219\or1391\or1564\or1736\or1908\or2079\or2250\or2419\or2588\or2756\or
  2924\or309\or3256\or342\or3584\or3746\fi\space}

Test: \pdfsave\pdfrotate{35}\rlap{don't use La\TeX}\pdfrestore

\bye
```

If you find something more straightforward, please, show it.