# \mathclap not centering

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, symbols, mathtools

I'm trying to stack two symbols on top of each other (not `\stackrel`) using `\mathclap` in the `mathtools` package, but the symbols are not centering:

```
\mathclap{\rightleftharpoons}\circ
```

How do I get the circle in the center of the arrows?

Answer (score 8):

This is a job for `\ooalign`:

```
\newcommand{\circrlh}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\docircrlh\relax}}
\newcommand{\docircrlh}[2]{%
  \ooalign{$#1\rightleftharpoons$\cr\hfil$#1\circ$\hfil\cr}}
```

Now with

```
$a\circrlh b_{\circrlh}$
```

you get the following result.

[image]

See [this answer for a quick course on `\ooalign`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/4427)