# koma script long chapter title

Tags: chapters, koma-script

I'm trying to get this chapter format. 
[image]
Unsuccessfully.

I'm using koma-sciript class. Based on [How to place the chapter number behind the chapter title in KOMA script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50448/how-to-place-the-chapter-number-behind-the-chapter-title-in-koma-script)

I've created:

```
    \makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {\hfill\makebox[0pt][r]{#2}\makebox[0.5\textwidth][l]{\parbox[b]{0.5\textwidth}{#3}}}%
    {\@hangfrom{#3}{#2}}% original definition for other commands with style=chapter
}
\makeatother
```

Should I put the chapter number and chapter title in separate minipages?
If so, in what way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {\hfill{\upshape#2}\parbox[b]{0.5\textwidth}{\raggedchapter #3}}%
    {\@hangfrom{#2}{#3}}% original definition for other commands with style=chapter
}
\makeatother
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\slshape}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Short title}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{Long, long, long chapter title}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]