# How to place the chapter number in the outside margins (using KOMA)

Tags: koma-script

In another question ([How to place the chapter number behind the chapter title in KOMA script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50448/how-to-place-the-chapter-number-behind-the-chapter-title-in-koma-script)) code was shown to have the chapter numer overprinting the chapter heading. I would like to have the chapter number (large) in the right (outside) margin.

I copy here the code from the previous solution which I do not fully understand but found working. What must be changed to have the number in the margin? Replacing `\textwidth` by `\pagewidth` did not work. I would appreciate some hints how to read the code.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\raggedleft}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \fontsize{60}{68}\selectfont\textcolor{lightgray}{\thechapter}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {\hfill\makebox[0pt][r]{#2}\makebox[0pt][r]{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\raggedchapter#3}}}%
    {\@hangfrom{#2}{#3}}% original definition for other commands with style=chapter
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\chapter{Text elements}
In this chapter, some textual elements are shown, like figures,
tables, lists, equations, etc. Also, bananas.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\raggedleft}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \rlap{\fontsize{60}{68}\selectfont\textcolor{lightgray}{\thechapter}}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {\hfill#2\makebox[0pt][r]{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\raggedchapter#3}}}%
    {\@hangfrom{#2}{#3}}% original definition for other commands with style=chapter
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\chapter{Text elements}
In this chapter, some textual elements are shown, like figures,
tables, lists, equations, etc. Also, bananas.
\end{document}
```

[image: number in outer margin]

---

Some explanations:

- The chapter number is stored in `\thechapter`, so we know we should modify the code containing `\thechapter`.
- The `\rlap` code creates a box of width zero, and then puts its contents hanging out to the right. You can play around with `\llap` too. With the `mathtools` package, there is `\clap`, and there are math mode equivalences: `\mathrlap`, `\mathllap` and `\mathclap`.
- I would recommend adding some space between chapter title and chapter number, so you may write `\rlap{ \fontsize...` (note the space added). This is of course my personal preference.

Comment: Two things: (1) The chapterformat is okay, but should be grouped (font selection), because when you do (2) remove the useless `\makebox` around `#2` in the lines format you could see some bad effects otherwise.

Comment: @TeXnician Ah yes, you are right! I didn’t even notice the `\makebox` situation.

Comment: I do not fully understand these two comments - could one of you fix the code to reflect the proposed improvement? Thank you!

Comment: It works as expected - great! Another "stupid" question: how to force the chapter title to be left justified?

Comment: @user855443 My current MWE *is improved*: 1) `\rlap` applies to the whole `\fontsize...\thechapter}` now. 2) The first `\makebox` in your `\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat` is unnecessary so it’s removed. Secondly, there’re no “stupid” questions. However, from your new question I got the impression that you simply copy-pasted the code from the other post *without understanding what it does*. **This is dangerous!** Perhaps you should first read [Koma-Script documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) pp. 471–472 to learn about `\chapterlinesformat`.

Comment: @user855443 Also, to my knowledge, there’s no such a thing called “left justified”. It’s either “flush left” (aka “ragged right”) or “justified”. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_alignment#Basic_variations). I have absolutely no idea what `\hfill#2\makebox[...` is trying to accomplish. So, again, you should read the documentation first to learn about customizing your chapter headings.

Comment: thank you for the pointer - the Koma-script doc is quite large and it is not always easy to find and understand the information given. I have learned a few things now, but do not fully understand the command yet.

Comment: @user855443 I think this might be what you want: From my MWE,1) remove `\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\raggedleft}`, and 2) change `\raggedchapter#3` to `\raggedright#3`. You may also want to change the `\parbox[b]` (bottom aligned) to `\parbox[t]` (top aligned) or to `\parbox[c]` (center aligned). I personally find `\parbox[t]` looks best.

Comment: thank you - that helps to understand me a few steps more. Indeed, `\parbox[t]` looks better!