# How to have chapter title overlap the chapter number?

Tags: formatting, chapters

I mean...something like this

[image]

If tried a lot of things: `overpic`, `textpos`, `tikz`, `titlesec`... but with no luck.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your document? Otherwise suggestions given here might not work for you...

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50469/36296 could help

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}

 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}%

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\bfseries\huge\sffamily\lsstyle\SetTracking[no ligatures = {f}]{encoding = *}{50}\filleft}
 {\scalebox{5}{\color{Gainsboro}\thechapter}\enspace}
 {-5.2ex}
 {\MakeUppercase}%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-60pt}{10ex}

\begin{document}

\chapter{QUÉ ES ANSIBLE}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]