# Reducing vertical space in stackrel

Tags: vertical-alignment

I often use the `stackrel` command within an equation in the following way

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi} + 1 \stackrel{\footnotemark}{=} 0
\end{equation}
\footnotetext{this is Euler's identity.}
%
\end{document}
```

I'd like to reduce the vertical distance between the `footnotemark` and the equal sign by default. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is based from a bit change of the code by the excellent user @egreg at this link:
[How can i shrink (or expand) the vertical spacing in \stackrel?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50962/how-can-i-shrink-or-expand-the-vertical-spacing-in-stackrel)

See the result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\nstackrel}{%
  \mathrel{\vbox{\offinterlineskip\ialign{%
    \hfil##\hfil\cr
    $\scriptscriptstyle\footnotemark$\cr
    \noalign{\kern-.3ex}
    $=$\cr
}}}}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi} + 1 \nstackrel 0
\end{equation}
\footnotetext{this is Euler's identity.}
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A `stackengine` approach.  You can adjust the 1st argument of `\stackengine` from `-1pt` to get the desired spacing.

You can use `\ftmk` before other symbols, as well, e.g., `+` and `-`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\ftmk[1]{\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{-1pt}{{}#1{}}{\footnotemark}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi} + 1 \ftmk= 0
\end{equation}
\footnotetext{this is Euler's identity.}
\end{document}
```

[image]