# Highlight a table row with a rectangular overlay

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I am trying to highlight the row of a table by drawing a rectangle over that row. A wrinkle is that the code for the table is pre-written from external statistical software and then included in the main document using the `\input` command. For this reason, I'd like to avoid placing code within the table, if at all possible. I have included a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\input{table.tex}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And the code for `table.tex` is:

```
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}}
& A & B & C \\
\hline
1 & blah & blah & blah \\
2 & blah & blah & blah \\
3 & blah & blah & blah \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I'd like to add a red rectangle (perhaps rounded) around the second row, possibly using tikz or some other solution. If it matters, the table will ultimately be in a `beamer` slide, but I figured that including that code was not necessary.

Comment: Do you have the capability of adding code to the table that is exported from the "external statistical software" package? So, instead of `blah`, you output `\somecode{stuff>}blah`?

Comment: I can go into `table.tex` and add the code. However, because the statistical process is rerun over and over again, I would like to avoid that if possible. I don't expect the spacing of the table to change much, e.g. there will always be 4 digit numbers in the cells, albeit different digits. So, if a rectangle is overlaid at the right coordinates once, I wouldn't have to change the code much thereafter, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Could you make the statistics software output just the raw numbers, without the LaTeX code? Then you could use `pgfplotstable` to typeset the table and add highlighting using the row number, or a keyword/key value.

Comment: Hi Jake, not sure I could use that solution, because the statistics software outputs table headings, and other labels, and sometimes latex code, not just numbers.

Comment: @stanford202: Ah, too bad. Never mind then.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could put the `\input` in a `node` and draw a rectangle relative to the corners of the node.

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{table.tex}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}}
& A & B & C \\
\hline
1 & blah & blah & blah \\
2 & blah & blah & blah \\
3 & blah & blah & blah \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (table) {\input{table.tex}};
\draw [red,ultra thick,rounded corners]
  ($(table.south west) !.3! (table.north west)$)
  rectangle 
  ($(table.south east) !.5! (table.north east)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Some explanation to the above code

There are several standard anchors on a `node` by default, denoted by compass directions, accessed with the syntax `<node name>.<anchor>`. For example will `MyNode.north west` be the top left corner of `MyNode`.

To get a coordinate between two existing coordinates you can use the TikZ library `calc`. This is described in section **13.5 Coordinate Calculations** of the [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz). It provides the syntax

```
($(<nodename or coordinate>) ! <factor> ! (<nodename or coordinate>)$)
```

Dollar signs indicate that a coordinate calculation should be done. The `<factor>` is a number saying how far, on the line between the two specified nodes, relative to the distance between the nodes, the point should be. For example,

```
($(0,0) !.3! (1,0)$)
```

is 30% of the way between `(0,0)` and `(1,0)`, meaning `(0.3,0)`.

In other words,

```
\draw [red,ultra thick,rounded corners]
  ($(table.south west) !.3! (table.north west)$)
  rectangle 
  ($(table.south east) !.5! (table.north east)$);
```

draws a `rectangle` from the point that is 30% of the distance from the lower left corner to the upper left corner, to the point that is halfway between the lower right and upper right corners.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Is there a reference in the `tikz` manual that I can use to decode your definition of the coordinates for the rectangle? This is for cases where the table is a different size, etc.

Comment: @stanford202: `TikZ` is part of `pgf` and is described inside the `pgf` documentation. So `texdoc pgfmanual.pdf` should open it.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation. That makes perfect sense. Yes, I meant to say the pgf manual.

Comment: is there a way to use xshift and y xshift in this code?

Comment: @leonardocesar Well in a coordinate calculation like that you can add coordinates, for example `($(table.south west) !.3! (table.north west) + (-1,-1)$)` to move that point 1 unit left and down. You can also shift the entire coordinate in the normal way, e.g. `([xshift=-5mm]$(table.south west) !.3! (table.north west)$)`

Answer (score 19):

Here's a sans-TikZ way of obtaining the rectangle via a coloured `\fbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newsavebox{\mytable}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{lrbox}{\mytable}
\input{table.tex}
\end{lrbox}
%\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}% Modify rule width if necessary
\ooalign{%
  \hss\usebox{\mytable}\hss \cr
  {\color{red}%
   \fbox{\phantom{\rule[-5pt]{\dimexpr\wd\mytable+10pt}{\dimexpr\baselineskip+5pt}}}%
  }
}
\end{center}

\end{document}​
```

The table `\input` is stored in a box `\mytable` in order to obtain the width. The box is subsequently positioned with a `5pt` overlap on either side of the table by setting a blank box of appropriate dimensions inside the coloured `\fbox`.

Within `\ooalign`, the table is centrred (since it's less wide than the `10pt`-wider `\fbox`) using `\hss`...`\hss`. This is overprint with the coloured `\fbox`. Here is a [quick course on `\ooalign`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/5764).

You could also reverse the sequence to use a shaded highlighting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newsavebox{\mytable}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{lrbox}{\mytable}
\input{table.tex}
\end{lrbox}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}% Modify rule width if necessary
\ooalign{%
  {\fcolorbox{red!50}{red!30}{%
     \phantom{\rule[-5pt]{\dimexpr\wd\mytable+10pt}{\dimexpr\baselineskip+5pt}}%
  }} \cr
  \hss\usebox{\mytable}\hss
}
\end{center}

\end{document}​
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to input the table into `tikz`, use this simple solution:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (5.5,5.3) rectangle (6.4,9.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Add this **after** the table if using overlays (e.g. `\visible<>{}`). Change the draw options and the coordinates manually. After a few iterations you will get it right.