# Fraction with doubled line

Tags: fractions

Is there a way to make the fraction line look like the equality (=) sign, i.e., to have two parallel horizontal lines with a little gap in between? Many thanks!

Comment: As a matter of curiosity what does this represent? Disclaimer, mathematically curious but not a mathematician.

Answer (score 14):

Use either `\Tfrac` or `\Dfrac` (short for Text and Display style "equal fraction") in the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newcommand{\Tfrac}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\genfrac{}{}{1.2pt}1{#1}{#2}$\cr%
    $\color{white}\genfrac{}{}{.4pt}1{\phantom{#1}}{\phantom{#2}}$}%
}
\newcommand{\Dfrac}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\genfrac{}{}{1.2pt}0{#1}{#2}$\cr%
    $\color{white}\genfrac{}{}{.4pt}0{\phantom{#1}}{\phantom{#2}}$}%
}
\begin{document}
$f(x)=\Tfrac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$
\end{document}
```

For a short course on `\ooalign`, see [`\subseteq` + `\circ` as a single symbol (“open subset”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/5764).

---

Here is a slightly modified set of commands: `\Efrac` and `\efrac`. While both adjust their fraction size based on the math style automatically (using `\mathchoice`), the former is vertically higher (set based on the height of the two outer black fraction lines) than the latter (set based on the height of a regular fraction).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newcommand{\Efrac}[2]{%
  \mathchoice
    {\ooalign{%
      $\genfrac{}{}{1.2pt}0{#1}{#2}$\cr%
      $\color{white}\genfrac{}{}{.4pt}0{\phantom{#1}}{\phantom{#2}}$}}%
    {\ooalign{%
      $\genfrac{}{}{1.2pt}1{#1}{#2}$\cr%
      $\color{white}\genfrac{}{}{.4pt}1{\phantom{#1}}{\phantom{#2}}$}}%
    {\ooalign{%
      $\genfrac{}{}{1.2pt}2{#1}{#2}$\cr%
      $\color{white}\genfrac{}{}{.4pt}2{\phantom{#1}}{\phantom{#2}}$}}%
    {\ooalign{%
      $\genfrac{}{}{1.2pt}3{#1}{#2}$\cr%
      $\color{white}\genfrac{}{}{.4pt}3{\phantom{#1}}{\phantom{#2}}$}}%
}
\newcommand{\efrac}[2]{%
  \mathchoice
    {\ooalign{%
      $\genfrac{}{}{1.2pt}0{\hphantom{#1}}{\hphantom{#2}}$\cr%
      $\color{white}\genfrac{}{}{.4pt}0{\color{black}#1}{\color{black}#2}$}}%
    {\ooalign{%
      $\genfrac{}{}{1.2pt}1{\hphantom{#1}}{\hphantom{#2}}$\cr%
      $\color{white}\genfrac{}{}{.4pt}1{\color{black}#1}{\color{black}#2}$}}%
    {\ooalign{%
      $\genfrac{}{}{1.2pt}2{\hphantom{#1}}{\hphantom{#2}}$\cr%
      $\color{white}\genfrac{}{}{.4pt}2{\color{black}#1}{\color{black}#2}$}}%
    {\ooalign{%
      $\genfrac{}{}{1.2pt}3{\hphantom{#1}}{\hphantom{#2}}$\cr%
      $\color{white}\genfrac{}{}{.4pt}3{\color{black}#1}{\color{black}#2}$}}%
}
\begin{document}
\[ f(x)={\textstyle\Efrac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}} \sim \Efrac{3}{4}+\frac{3}{4} \]
\[ f(x)={\textstyle\efrac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}} \sim \efrac{3}{4}+\frac{3}{4} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I accidentally made a duplicate here— http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295739/how-to-make-an-extensible-double-faction-bar—because when I searched for existing answers I looked for "double bar" or "double slash." I would like to know how to modify this answer a bit to play with spacing, if you have a moment. Particularly, I'd like to be able to change the spaces between the numerator and denominator and the pair of lines, and the space between the two lines. How could I do that?

Comment: The above approach prints the fraction twice: first with a very thick `1.2pt` rule, then overprints it with a thin white `.4pt` rule that also sets the numerator `#1` and denominator `#2`. Since `\genfrac` is vertically centered on the math axis, the overprinting of the thin white on thick black rule leaves a `.4pt` black rule at the top and bottom. If you want a thicker rule, you can adjust the `1.2pt` value and/or `.4pt` value.

Comment: I found a solution by printing the `\genfrac` 3 times, 2 with phantoms, so I can exactly control the spacing between the denom and nom.

Answer (score 3):

A solution without colors, which could break in case of colored background.

The fraction is typeset twice: the first time it is raised and the denominator is a phantom; the second time it is lowered and the numerator is a phantom. The two are superimposed with the help of `\ooalign`.

The gap is customizable with the parameter `\doublefracgap`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\doublefracgap}
\setlength{\doublefracgap}{0.75pt}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\doublefrac}[2]{%
  \mathinner{\mathpalette\doublefrac@{{#1}{#2}}}%
}
\newcommand{\doublefrac@}[2]{\doublefrac@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\doublefrac@@}[3]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \raisebox{\doublefracgap}{$\m@th#1\frac{#2}{\phantom{#3}}$}\cr
    \raisebox{-\doublefracgap}{$\m@th#1\frac{\phantom{#2}}{#3}$}\cr
  }%
}
\newcommand{\ddoublefrac}[2]{{\displaystyle\doublefrac{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\tdoublefrac}[2]{{\textstyle\doublefrac{#1}{#2}}}
\makeatother

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt} % just for the example
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\[
\doublefrac{1}{2}\ne\frac{1}{2} \qquad \sqrt{\doublefrac{x^2+2}{x^2-1}}
\]
\[
\frac{1}{2}\ne\doublefrac{1}{2}
\]
$\doublefrac{1}{2}\ne\frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{1}{2}\ne\doublefrac{1}{2}$

$\ddoublefrac{1}{2}\ne\dfrac{1}{2}$

$\dfrac{1}{2}\ne\ddoublefrac{1}{2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looking at the various fractions the presence of the double fraction lines increases the distance. You can see that, for example, the number 1 with the fraction of the double lines does not line up with the number 1 of the classic fraction line. +1