# How to make an extensible double-fraction bar

Tags: fractions

I want to express a certain kind of quotient with a double-bar. The solution to the question this is a duplicate of ([Fraction with doubled line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56003/579)) works for me, but I'd like to tinker with it a bit regarding

1. the spaces between numerator/demominator and bars
2. the spaces between the two bars
3. the width of the bars

to achieve an aesthetic closer to the rest of my document.

What parameters can I modify?

Comment: Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56003/fraction-with-doubled-line ?

Comment: Nope! Thanks, that works, and this one should be closed as a duplicate. That said, what parameters could I fiddle with to adjust the spacing? (Right now, e.g., I think the numerator and denominator are too far from the fraction double-line, and the space between the two lines is a little too small.)

Comment: Address a comment to the answerer (or change the question so it states the real problem you're facing with that solution). For the moment, I'll vote for closing, let me know what you decide.

Comment: I'll put it as a comment there for now!

Comment: Okay, I posted a comment on the original solution. I'll only modify this one if it doesn't get answered there. Thanks for explaining the procedure to me.

Comment: All right, I modified this question. It now asks how to change the parameters in the old answers.