# Fraction with double line with ams environment

Tags: fractions

I am not sure if this counts as a duplicate question, but I would like to have a fraction where the delimiter consists of two lines. I tried using the Tfrac solution at [Fraction with doubled line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56003/fraction-with-doubled-line) and it works fine, until I use an ams environment in the denominator and get the following output

[image]

I assume it is related to the usage of `ooalign`. I tried to look up online how I should go about this, but I can't seem to find much.

My code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor

\newcommand{\Tfrac}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\genfrac{}{}{1.2pt}1{#1}{#2}$\cr%
    $\color{white}\genfrac{}{}{.4pt}1{\phantom{#1}}{\phantom{#2}}$}%
}

$
\Tfrac
    {
        \phantom{test}
    }
    {
        \mathtt{B} \oplus \{\mathit{repeat}:\, \mathtt{B?[int]; S'}\}
        \, \leq \,
        \mathtt{B \oplus}
        \left\{
        \begin{aligned}
            & \mathit{notify} : \mathtt{B![bool]; end} \\
            & \mathit{repeat}: S_4 \\
            & \mathit{stop}: \mathtt{end} \\
        \end{aligned}
        \right\}
    }
$
```

Edit:
To show the intended use, I would like to end up with something like this, but with double lined fractions instead.

[image]

Comment: Is there *something* above the two lines?

Comment: From your example it looks more like you want a double accent bar.

Comment: In this example no, however there will be cases where I will also have these type of fractions as the numerator. The end result would be a derivation tree, so I would ideally need to be able to nest these fractions, which I currently can, as long as I don't use the ams environment

Comment: @Filu I believe you're using the wrong tool.

Comment: @egreg could you please guide me in the right direction? I will also add an example of how I would like to use it later on, to maybe give a better explanation of what I mean by nested

Comment: @Filu There are several packages to display derivations.

Comment: @egreg thank you for suggesting this, I found the ```ebproof``` package and it seems much more suited for what I want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're using the wrong tool. Anyway, a simple modification of my code in another answer to the question you link to will do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\doublefracgap}
\setlength{\doublefracgap}{0.75pt}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\doublefrac}[2]{%
  \mathinner{\mathpalette\doublefrac@{{#1}{#2}}}%
}
\newcommand{\doublefrac@}[2]{\doublefrac@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\doublefrac@@}[3]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \raisebox{\doublefracgap}{\normalbaselines$\m@th#1\frac{#2}{\phantom{#3}}$}\cr
    \raisebox{-\doublefracgap}{\normalbaselines$\m@th#1\frac{\phantom{#2}}{#3}$}\cr
  }%
}
\newcommand{\ddoublefrac}[2]{{\displaystyle\doublefrac{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\tdoublefrac}[2]{{\textstyle\doublefrac{#1}{#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\doublefrac
    {
        \phantom{test}
    }
    {
        \mathtt{B} \oplus \{\mathit{repeat}:\, \mathtt{B?[int]; S'}\}
        \, \leq \,
        \mathtt{B} \oplus
        \left\{
        \begin{aligned}
            & \mathit{notify} : \mathtt{B![bool]; end} \\
            & \mathit{repeat}: S_4 \\
            & \mathit{stop}: \mathtt{end} \\
        \end{aligned}
        \right\}
    }
\]

\end{document}
```

The difference is in the `\normalbaselines` declarations.

I fixed `\mathtt{B\oplus}` to `\mathtt{B}\oplus`, as the former is wrong as it produces wrong spacing (and `\mathtt` around `\oplus` does nothing at all).

[image]