# Setting two math symbols directly above each other and vertically aligned

Tags: symbols, amsmath

I am typesetting the Neyman Pearson decision rule and would like to set the greater than `>` and smaller than `<` symbols directly above each other. I tried `\overset` but that doesn't align the resulting two symbols vertically to the middle.

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol).

Comment: Thanks, good link. I have the not so short introduction to latex, but managed to miss the specific symbol..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course, there's always `\gtrless` from

```
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
```

If you're not up for using packages, you could rather "overset" the symbols yourself:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\npsym}{%
  \mathrel{\ooalign{\raisebox{.6ex}{$>$}\cr\raisebox{-.6ex}{$<$}}}
}
\begin{document}
Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
See, for example, $x\npsym y$. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

See [`\subseteq` + `\circ` as a single symbol (“open subset”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/5764) for a short course in `\ooalign`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I also found that my specific case has math symbol, \gtrless.

Comment: I don't think that `\ooalign` is the best way to cope with this problem.

Answer (score 7):

Where `\grtless` not available, one could define it with a tabular; for efficiency, it's better to use primitive commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

% This won't do anything if amssymb is loaded first
\providecommand{\gtrless}{
  \mathrel{% it's a relation
  \smash{% we don't want that it influences the interline spacing
  \vcenter{% the symbol will be vertically centered
    \offinterlineskip % no interline skip here
    \ialign{% build a table
       \hfil##\hfil\cr % just one centered column
       $>$\cr % first row
       \noalign{\kern-.3ex}% shorten the vertical distance
       $<$\cr % second row
    }% end of the \ialign
  }% end of \vcenter
  }% end of \smash
  \vphantom{>}% pretend it's as high as a >
  }% end of \mathrel
}

\begin{document}
Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
See, for example, $x\gtrless y$. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why is this better that Werner's solution? Both need to use some manual spacing adjustment.

Comment: @Caramdir This one is more efficient in terms of computations; it would be a breeze if we avoided `\smash` and `\phantom`, which is clearly possible, for it uses only primitives, except `\ialign` that's `\halign` together with two assignments.