# Creating math symbol by stacking and superimposing symbols

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'd like to have the usual symbol for the infimal convolution. I've tried `\stackrel{+}{\vee}`, but it scales down the plus, which I don't want. I also tried `\atop`, but the symbol gets really big and ugly. I'd like something more like `\pm`... But unfortunately I'm having a hard time finding its code.

Comment: Can you add a link to some place where we can see this usual symbol?

Comment: Maybe you want `\star`?

Comment: well, no. I only have a (physical) book with the symbol, and it is regularly used handwritten in my research group.  I actually think I solved my problem, but I'm not sure if the symbol will scale with math fonts.  `\newcommand\plusvee{\mathrel{\ooalign{\lower.5ex
\hbox{$\scriptstyle\vee\mkern.5mu$}\cr\hidewidth\raise.450ex
\hbox{$\scriptstyle+$}\cr}}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Infimal convolution symbols across the Internet vary, so this one is taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Infimal_convolution):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\iconv}{\mathbin{\star_{\text{inf}}}}%
\begin{document}
\[ (f\iconv g)(x) = \inf\{f(x-y)+g(y)\,\vert\,y\in\mathbb{R}^n\} \]
\end{document}
```

Here's another one taken from [this source](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/0897-10.pdf):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\DeclareMathOperator{\iconv}{%
  \mathbin{\ooalign{\raisebox{-.5ex}{$\vee$}\cr\hidewidth\raisebox{.5ex}{\scalebox{.7}{+}}\hidewidth}}}%
\begin{document}
\[ (f\iconv g)(x) = \inf\{f(x-y)+g(y)\,\vert\,y\in\mathbb{R}^n\} \]
\end{document}
```

Or, create it yourself (from the above, and therefore does not require [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\iconv}{%
  \mathbin{\ooalign{\raisebox{-.5ex}{$\triangledown$}\cr\hidewidth\rule[.3ex]{.4pt}{1ex}\hidewidth}}}%
\begin{document}
\[ (f\iconv g)(x) = \inf\{f(x-y)+g(y)\,\vert\,y\in\mathbb{R}^n\} \]
\end{document}
```

If you're going to use these symbols in super-/subscripts, then more works needs to be done. The use of `\ooalign` for symbol construction is discussed in [`\subseteq` + `\circ` as a single symbol (“open subset”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/5764).

Comment: Thanks. The symbol I was looking for is a plus sign over a vee. But you gave me an idea: maybe I should use `\mathbin` instead of `\mathrel`, which I am using now...