# How to make a plus sign with arrowheads on each of the four endpoints?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

There is a common operation in the [sparse-direct literature (see pg. 7)](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~xiaj/work/mfhssrs.pdf) called an "extend-add", and it is usually denoted with a particular symbol that looks like a large plus sign with arrowheads on each tip.

[image]

I falsely assumed that I could simply overlap `$\updownarrow$` and `$\leftrightarrow$` via the `mathtools` package's `\mathllap` and friends, but the results were far from pleasing (everything was too jumbled).

Is there a simpler way to generate such a symbol?

Comment: I feel a good solution should ensure that the new sign is exactly as big (wide & high) as the plus sign (and consequently none of the solutions are quite there yet …)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Simple overlapping

The overlapping of the symbols `\leftrightarrow` and `\updownarrow` can be done with
`\ooalign`:

```
\ooalign{$\leftrightarrow$\cr\hfil$\updownarrow$\hfil}
```

Some additional work is needed:

- Adapting to different math styles. The formula above would always use `\textstyle`.
- If `\mathsurround` is set, then the additional space would be added above to the
  left and right. This can be cured by `\m@th` that sets `\mathsurround` to zero.
- The symbol is used as binary operator, putting it in `\mathbin` notifies TeX to
  put additinal space for binary operators.

File:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{txfonts} % similar \usepacakge{pxfonts}
% \usepackage{mathabx}
% \usepackage{MnSymbol}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\extendadd}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\extend@add{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\extend@add}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\leftrightarrow$%
    \vphantom{$\m@th#1\updownarrow$}% fix the height
    \cr
    \hfil$\m@th#1\updownarrow$\hfil
  }%   
}
\makeatother

% for testing the bounding box of the symbol
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.2pt}

\begin{document}
\[
  \mathcal{F}_\mathbf{i} =
  \mathcal{F}_\mathbf{i}^0
  \extendadd
  \mathcal{U}_{\mathbf{c}_1}
  \extendadd
  \mathcal{U}_{\mathbf{c}_2}
  \qquad
  \fbox{$\extendadd$}^{\extendadd^{\extendadd}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Result for CM fonts:

> [image: CM large]

Result for package `txfonts`:

> [image: TX large]

Result for package `mathabx`:

> [image: mathabx large]

Result for package `MnSymbol`:

> [image: MnSymbol large]

**Observations:**

- The arrow heads are too large.
- Depending on the font and size `\updownarrow` might have a smaller total height
  than the width of `\leftrightarrow`.

### Overlapping with resizing

The idea is to resize `\longleftrightarrow` to the width of `\leftrightarrow` to get
smaller arrow heads. However, this will also make the lines thinner.

The tricky part is that scaling also changes the vertical position of the symbol.
Because of the arrows the height of the character bounding box `\leftrightarrow` is not too helpful. But we can assume the symbol is vertically centered respective to the mathematical axis. Therefore the code below puts `\leftrightarrow` to the base line, resizes it and moves it back to the mathematical axis.
to the mathematical axis.

The vertical double arrow cannot generated the same way. First the symbol `\longupdownarrow` is missing. Also we have seen above, that the symbol might be
too small in comparison with the `\leftrightarrow`. Therefore the symbol is generated by rotating the horizontal double arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{txfonts}
% \usepackage{pxfonts}
% \usepackage{mathabx}
% \usepackage{MnSymbol}

\usepackage{graphicx}% (only graphics is needed)

\makeatletter
\newdimen\extend@width
\newdimen\extend@mathaxis
\newcommand*{\extendadd}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\extend@add{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\extend@add}[2]{%
  \m@th
  \sbox0{$#1\vcenter{}\smash{\leftrightarrow}$}%
  \extend@width=\wd0 %
  \extend@mathaxis=\ht0 %
  \sbox0{%
    \resizebox{\extend@width}{!}{%
      \raisebox{-\extend@mathaxis}{$#1\longleftrightarrow$}%
    }%
  }%
  \rlap{%
    \raisebox{\extend@mathaxis}{%
      \copy0 %
    }%
  }%
  \dp0=0pt %
  \ht0=0pt %
  \hbox to\extend@width{%
    \hfil
    $#1%
      \vcenter{%
        \hbox{%
          \rotatebox{90}{\copy0}%
        }%
      }%
    $%
    \hfil
  }%
}
\makeatother

% for testing the bounding box of the symbol
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.2pt}

\begin{document}
\[
  \mathcal{F}_\mathbf{i} =
  \mathcal{F}_\mathbf{i}^0
  \extendadd
  \mathcal{U}_{\mathbf{c}_1}
  \extendadd  
  \mathcal{U}_{\mathbf{c}_2}
  \qquad
  \fbox{$\extendadd$}^{\extendadd^{\extendadd}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Result for CM fonts:

> [image: CM scaled]

Result for package `txfonts`:

> [image: TX scaled]

Result for package `mathabx`:

> [image: mathabx scaled]

Result for package `MnSymbol`:

> [image: MnSymbol scaled]

It is also possible to have something in between, less scaling, by composing
a smaller `\longleftrightarrow` from `\leftarrow` and `\rightarrow` as base for the resized double arrow.

Comment: Wow! Truely a wizard ;) +1

Answer (score 23):

## Ti*k*Z solutions

### Same sized

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}

\makeatletter
%% internal macros
\newlength\jack@depth
\def\jack@factor{0.2} % adjust this for the size of arrows
\def\jack@arrow{to}
\def\jack@arrowshorten{3}

% external macro
\newcommand*\extendadd{\mathbin{\mskip1mu\mathpalette\jack@extendadd{}\mskip1mu}}
\def\jack@extendadd#1{\ifx#1\scriptstyle\def\jack@linewidth{.6pt/\jack@factor}
           \else\ifx#1\scriptscriptstyle\def\jack@linewidth{.62pt/\jack@factor}
           \else                        \def\jack@linewidth{.54pt/\jack@factor}
           \fi\fi
  \setlength{\jack@depth}{\depthof{$#1+$}}
  \raisebox{-\jack@depth}{\resizebox{!}{\heightof{$#1+$}+\depthof{$#1+$}}{\jack@plusarrow}}
}

\def\jack@plusarrow{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[
      \jack@arrow-\jack@arrow,
      shorten >=-\jack@arrowshorten\pgflinewidth,
      shorten <=-\jack@arrowshorten\pgflinewidth
    ]
      \draw[line width=\jack@linewidth] (1ex/\jack@factor,0) -- (-1ex/\jack@factor,0);
      \draw[line width=\jack@linewidth] (0,1ex/\jack@factor) -- (0,-1ex/\jack@factor);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother

\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\setlength\fboxrule{.2pt}
\begin{document}\noindent
$ \fbox{+}\fbox{$\extendadd$}_{+\extendadd_{+\extendadd}} $\\
\makeatletter
\foreach \arrow in {to,stealth',angle 90} {+%
    \foreach \factor in {.1,.2,...,1.01} {%
        \renewcommand*\jack@factor{\factor}%
        \renewcommand*\jack@arrow{\arrow}%
        \renewcommand*\jack@arrowshorten{3/\factor*.2}%
        ${\extendadd}$%
    }\\}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: same sized]

### Bigger than normal plus sign

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\plusarrowlength{2.5pt}
\newcommand{\plusarrow}{\mathbin{\text{$
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    baseline,
%   opacity=.7 % debugging (doesn't have any effect when \phantom is used)
    ]
    \node[
        inner xsep=-1pt,
        inner ysep=-.5pt,
        outer sep=0pt,
        anchor=base
        ] (plus) {\phantom{+}};
    \begin{scope}[to-to]
        \draw ($(plus.west)+(-\plusarrowlength,0)$) -- ($(plus.east)+(\plusarrowlength,0)$);
        \draw ($(plus.north)+(0,\plusarrowlength)$) -- ($(plus.south)+(0,-\plusarrowlength)$);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}$}}}

\begin{document}\noindent
$ \plusarrow_{\plusarrow_{\plusarrow}} $ \\
$ +_{+_+} $
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: bigger]

### Extra arrow tip

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newdimen\arrowsize
\pgfarrowsdeclare{arcs}{arcs}{
    \arrowsize=0.2pt
    \advance\arrowsize by .5\pgflinewidth
    \pgfarrowsleftextend{-4\arrowsize-.5\pgflinewidth}
    \pgfarrowsrightextend{.5\pgflinewidth}
}{
    \arrowsize=2\pgflinewidth
    \pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
    \pgfsetroundjoin
    \pgfsetroundcap
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\arrowsize}{\arrowsize}}
    \pgfpatharc{180}{270}{\arrowsize}
    \pgfpatharc{90}{180}{\arrowsize}
    \pgfusepathqstroke
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\extendadd{\mathbin{\mskip1mu\mathpalette\plusarrow{}\mskip1mu}}
\newcommand{\plusarrow}[1]{
\ifx#1\displaystyle
    \def\jack@innerxsep{-.55pt}
    \def\jack@innerysep{0pt}
    \def\jack@linewidth{.4pt}
\else\ifx#1\textstyle
        \def\jack@innerxsep{-.55pt}
        \def\jack@innerysep{0pt}
        \def\jack@linewidth{.4pt}
    \else\ifx#1\scriptstyle
            \def\jack@innerxsep{-.5pt}
            \def\jack@innerysep{0pt}
            \def\jack@linewidth{.35pt}
        \else
            \def\jack@innerxsep{-.5pt}
            \def\jack@innerysep{0pt}
            \def\jack@linewidth{.3pt}
        \fi
    \fi
\fi
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    baseline,
%   opacity=.7 % debugging (doesn't have any effect when \phantom is used)
    ]
    \node[
        inner xsep=\jack@innerxsep,
        inner ysep=\jack@innerysep,
        outer sep=0pt,
        anchor=base
        ] (plus) {\phantom{$#1+$}};
    \begin{scope}[arcs-arcs]
        \draw[line width=\jack@linewidth] (plus.west) -- (plus.east);
        \draw[line width=\jack@linewidth] (plus.north) -- (plus.south);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}\noindent
$ \extendadd_{\extendadd_{\extendadd}} $ \\
$ +_{+_+} $
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: extra arrow]

## Xe-/LuaLaTeX (without Ti*k*Z)

This solution works only for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX with the `unicode-math` package and OpenType fonts that include the symbols `\neswarrow` and `\nwsearrow`. (This is my favorite output.)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\newcommand{\plusarrow}{\mathbin{\text{\rotatebox[]{45}{\ooalign{$\nwsearrow$\cr$\neswarrow$}}}}}
\begin{document}
$ 7 \plusarrow 8$ \quad $ \plusarrow_{\plusarrow_{\plusarrow}} $
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: XeLaTeX solution]

Answer (score 10):

Another option; no TikZ required and the use of \mathchoice allows correct scaling according to the math style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\ArrPlus{%
\setbox0\hbox{$\longleftrightarrow$}%
\rlap{\hbox to \wd0{\hss\rotatebox[origin=top]{90}{\scalebox{.9}{$\longleftrightarrow$}}\hss}}\raise.15ex\box0}
\def\arrowplus{\mathbin{%
\mathchoice
  {\scalebox{.7}{\ArrPlus}}
  {\scalebox{.7}{\ArrPlus}}
  {\scalebox{.35}{\raisebox{.2ex}{\ArrPlus}}}
  {\scalebox{.25}{\raisebox{.35ex}{\ArrPlus}}}
}}

\begin{document}


$ A \arrowplus B\quad{\displaystyle A \arrowplus B}\quad M_{A \arrowplus B}\quad L_{M_{A \arrowplus B}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There should be better ways of doing this. But here are some options:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\arrowplus}{%
{\mathbin{\text{%
\ensuremath{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-.3em]
  \draw [<->,thin] (0,0) -- (1.1em,0);
  \draw [<->,thin] (.55em,-.55em) -- (.55em,.55em);
\end{tikzpicture}
}}}}}

%
\newcommand{\arowplus}{%
\scalebox{.8}{\raisebox{.35em}{\ensuremath\longleftrightarrow\kern-1.05em\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}
{\ensuremath\longleftrightarrow}\kern.65em
}}}
\def\Arrowplus{\mathbin{%
\mathchoice
  {\scalebox{.7}{\arowplus}}
  {\scalebox{.7}{\arowplus}}
  {\scalebox{.4}{\raisebox{.2ex}{\arowplus}}}
  {\scalebox{.3}{\raisebox{.35ex}{\arowplus}}}
}}


\begin{document}
\[
  \Arrowplus \qquad \arrowplus
\]

\[
 A \arrowplus B\quad{\displaystyle A \arrowplus B}\quad M_{A \arrowplus B}\quad L_{M_{A \arrowplus B}}
 \]
\[
 A \Arrowplus B\quad{\displaystyle A \Arrowplus B}\quad M_{A \Arrowplus B}\quad L_{M_{A \Arrowplus B}}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't the use of `\mathbin` be better instead of `\,`?

Answer (score 6):

Another solution, non-`tikz` using one of [@egreg's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) favourite tools, `ooalign`

[image]

For a tutorial on `ooalign` see

[\subseteq + \circ as a single symbol ("open subset")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/subseteq-circ-as-a-single-symbol-open-subset/22375#22375)

Note that in the code below I have redefined the commands `\leftrightarrow` and `\updownarrow` to take optional arguments that will scale them (default is no scaling). This means that you could use, for example

```
\newcommand\arrowplus{\mathbin{\ooalign{$\updownarrow[1.1]$\cr\hidewidth$\leftrightarrow$\hidewidth}}}
```

which will scale the `updownarrow` by a factor of `1.1`.

I've loaded the `MnSymbol` package simply because I liked the look of its arrows- it does modify other symbols, so use load it carefully.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

% renew command to scale the leftrightarrow
\let\oldleftrightarrow\leftrightarrow
\renewcommand{\leftrightarrow}[1][3]{\scalebox{#1}{$\oldleftrightarrow$}}

% renew command to scale the updownarrow
\let\oldupdownarrow\updownarrow
\renewcommand{\updownarrow}[1][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$\oldupdownarrow$}}


\newcommand\arrowplus{\mathbin{\ooalign{$\updownarrow$\cr\hidewidth$\leftrightarrow$\hidewidth}}}

\begin{document}

$A\arrowplus B$
\end{document}
```

Comment: It could probably be done with `mathclap` from the `mathtools` package as well, but I don't think it's as elegant