Looking for a fancy plus and minus symbol
I am looking for the following symbols (ignore the subscript G), which are somewhat thicker/fancier versions of the plus and minus signs. I do not have any attempt, as I have no idea how to make this exact symbol using TikZ with the right spacing etc.


I do not have any attempt, as I have no idea how to make this exact symbol using TikZ with the right spacing etc. I tried using Detexify, but could not find anything. Also, I am not sure what tag is really applicable here.
EDIT
I will add screenshots of pages where this symbol appears, for possible context about the font etc.

(Combinatorial Game Theory, by Siegel)

(Lessons in Play, by Albert, Nowakowski, Wolfe)

see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78604/36296 about how to create your own plus signs

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: I don't really understand the codes in that answers, and I do not see how I could create my symbol with the kind of examples there.

As @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz mentioned the link, you can try with this part \documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{unicode-math} \setmathfont{XITS Math} \newcommand{\plusarrow}{\mathbin{\text{\rotatebox[]{45}{\ooalign{$\nwsearrow$\cr$\neswarrow$}}}}} \begin{document} $ 7 \plusarrow 8$ \quad $ \plusarrow_{\plusarrow_{\plusarrow}} $ \end{document}

@MadyYuvi: That changes the math font, which I do not want. Also, could you give some start as to how I could modify this to my case? Sorry if it is too obvious, but I am not that well-versed with these kind of commands.

is that a + or a maltese cross ✠ ?

If. you. know how to use. a. font editor, and.  know. how. to enable a custom font. in LaTeX, you can. do it that way. I. do it all the time,  because. the font editor (FontForge)  has GUI.

@DavidCarlisle: I don't know the origin. But it is standard notation in combinatorial game theory. If you have a game G, you can define these two games tiny-G and miny-G respectively.

That page doesn't seem to have the symbol. If you have a pdf showing it you can see what character and font it is

@DavidCarlisle: Oh I am sorry, I meant that as a link for the subject. The symbol can be found in this book Combinatorial Game Theory by Aaron Siegel on page 89, and in the book Lessons in Play by Albert, Nowakowski, Wolfe on page 127.

@DavidCarlisle: I added some screenshots.

You could build symbols that look like that by stacking rescaled black triangles.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength{\signwidth}
\newlength{\signheight}
\newcommand*{\fancyline}[1]{%
    \ooalign{%
        \scalebox{1}[0.2]{$#1\blacktriangleright$}\cr%
        \scalebox{1}[0.2]{$#1\blacktriangleleft$}%
    }%   
}
\newcommand*{\fancyminussign}[1]{%
    \settoheight{\signheight}{\fancyline{#1}}%
    \raisebox{1.5\signheight}{\fancyline{#1}}%
}
\newcommand*{\fancyplussign}[1]{%
    \settowidth{\signwidth}{\fancyline{#1}}%
    \settoheight{\signheight}{\fancyline{#1}}%
    \raisebox{1.5\signheight}{\ooalign{%
        \fancyline{#1}\cr%
        \hskip\dimexpr 0.5\signwidth - 0.5\signheight%
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\fancyline{#1}}%
    }}%
}
\newcommand*{\fancyminus}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\fancyminussign{}}}
\newcommand*{\fancyplus}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\fancyplussign{}}}
\begin{document}
\(x \fancyminus y \quad
\textstyle x \fancyminus y \quad
\scriptstyle x \fancyminus y \quad
\scriptscriptstyle x \fancyminus y\)

\(x - y \quad
\textstyle x - y \quad
\scriptstyle x - y \quad
\scriptscriptstyle x - y\)

\(x \fancyplus y \quad
\textstyle x \fancyplus y \quad
\scriptstyle x \fancyplus y \quad
\scriptscriptstyle x \fancyplus y\)

\(x + y \quad
\textstyle x + y \quad
\scriptstyle x + y \quad
\scriptscriptstyle x + y\)
\end{document}


Thanks a lot! I wanted a bigger symbol, but that was easily fixed by a scalebox.

@ultralegend5385 Instead of adding another scalebox (which could mess up the sizes in sub/superscripts), you could also adjust the scaling factors in the scaleboxes in \fancyline's definition.

These symbols can be found in the combgames package, which is available at http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/lessonsinplay/latex-macros/.
Unfortunately, it requires pstricks, which can make compilation somewhat more difficult, but it means you don't have to "approximate" the symbol with tikz.

This answer could benefit from a picture of potential plus and minus symbols. Sometimes a quick view helps people decide if the effort is worth using pstricks.

The link is broken.
