# Defining a new binary operator

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to find a way to define the `%` symbol as a binary operator that behaves essentially like the `+` symbol. I have heard of the command `DeclareMathOperator`, but I was under the impression that this was for operators like the logarithm and sine functions. What is an appropriate command? An an example, I would like the following to lines to have similar spacing.

```
\begin{equation*}
a % b % c
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
a + b + c
\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If using macros to represent the new symbol is fine, then you have a couple of options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\percA}{\mathbin{\%}}
\newcommand{\percB}{\mathbin{\ooalign{$\hidewidth\%\hidewidth$\cr$\phantom{+}$}}}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{|@{}c@{}|}
  a \percA b \percA c \\[\jot] % Option A
  a \percB b \percB c \\[\jot] % Option B
  a + b + c % Control
\end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

Option A `\percA` inserts `\%` as a binary math symbol using `\mathbin{\%}`. However, `\%` is slightly wider than `+`. That's where option B provides `\percB` which oversets a zero-width `\%` with a `\phantom{+}`.

For the inner working behind `\ooalign`, see [`\subseteq` + `\circ` as a single symbol (“open subset”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/5764).

Comment: Why the Google short link? I don't remember exactly where, but I think short links are generally frowned upon on SE.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29518/162565, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99136/162565, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64450/162565 -- not a clear ban of shortened URLs, but definitely a distinct dislike.

Comment: @doncherry: The motivation was purely out of self-interest to track badge progress, since Google's URL shortner provides a "CLICKS" tally. There's no other way to estimate progress on badges like [Announcer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/57/announcer), [Booster](http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/58/booster) or [Publicist](http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/59/publicist). Do you know whether a tool for tracking these badges exist, even through some Ninja search or the Data Explorer?

Comment: No, none that I know of. While I don't think it's very likely, there might yet be one; I just recently learned that anonymous and low-rep user feedback is accessible via data.se .. even though it seems broken now, these queries used to work: http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/73917/anonymous-feedback-for-a-specific-question-and-its-answers, http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/60668/feedback-on-my-posts

Comment: @doncherry: This seems to still be an open question on Meta.SO, dating back to 2010: [View progress towards Announcer badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67240/view-progress-towards-announcer-badge). Even then, [one of the mods "suggest" a URL shortner](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67240/view-progress-towards-announcer-badge#comment161635_67240). `:-|`

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but here's what I believe to be a better proposal: the percent character at its natural size is too prominent, so I scale it to have the same width as `+` (but also adding some sidebearing).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\perc}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\scaletoplus@{\mkern1mu\%\mkern1mu}}%
}
\newcommand{\scaletoplus@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \hbox{\sbox\z@{$\m@th#1+$}\resizebox{\wd\z@}{!}{$\m@th#1#2$}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\perc b \cdot c + d_{u\perc v}$

$a+b$

\end{document}
```

[image]