# Wedge with vertical bar

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm making a summary sheet of a course in LaTeX. There are, however, I have no idea how to draw two of the symbols. One of them is some sort of `\wedge` with a vertical bar through it, the other a `\vee` with a vertical bar through it, as shown below:

[image: Picture of symbols]

Any ideas how I could compose such a symbol?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This overlaps three things: wedge/vee, shortmid, and shortmid raised to a correct height. The numbers suit `cm` and `lm` fonts, for other fonts they might need to be modified.

See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/11002) for a quick course on `\ooalign`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@@vertwv[3]{\mathop{\ooalign{%
  $#1#3$\cr
  \hfil$#1\shortmid$\hfil\cr
  \hfil\raisebox{#2}{$#1\shortmid$}\hfil\cr}}}
\newcommand\@vertwv[1]{\mathchoice
  {\@@vertwv{\displaystyle     }{0.38ex}{#1}}%
  {\@@vertwv{\textstyle        }{0.38ex}{#1}}%
  {\@@vertwv{\scriptstyle      }{0.28ex}{#1}}%
  {\@@vertwv{\scriptscriptstyle}{0.21ex}{#1}}}
\newcommand\vertwedge{\@vertwv\wedge}
\newcommand\vertvee  {\@vertwv\vee  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[ a\vertwedge b \neq a\vertvee b \]
\[ \textstyle a\vertwedge b \neq a\vertvee b \]
\[ \scriptstyle a\vertwedge b \neq a\vertvee b \]
\[ \scriptscriptstyle a\vertwedge b \neq a\vertvee b \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: How did you choose the sizes for the various math styles? Did you just use trial and error to make the scaling consistent with built-in letters like 'a' and 'b', or is there some systematic way?

Answer (score 5):

For users of XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX exist with the `unicode-math` package and the fonts XITS Math, Asana Math and (according to the `unciode-math` symbol list) Lucida Math the macros

- `\veemidvert` and
- `\wedgemidvert`

to access these symbols.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% not needed but used for this example and the align environment
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
%\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
      x \veemidvert y \leq z & \equiv x \leq z \wedge y \leq z \\
    z \leq x \wedgemidvert y & \equiv z \leq x \wedge z \leq y
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

### Output

The top rows show XITS Math, the bottom ones show Asana Math.

[image]