# $<$ and $>$ signs with vertical lines through them in overleaf?

Tags: symbols

I am trying to find the symbol code for $<,>$ with vertical lines through them, to use in overleaf. In the wiki page for latex symbols it doesn't have such a thing... Are there any packages that contain this? Or could I define it somehow along the lines of what is done in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91038/wedge-with-vertical-bar)?

Comment: See [the comprehensive LaTeX symbols list](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) and look for "Inequalities".

Comment: `mathabx` has `\nless` and `\ngtr`.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you!

Comment: @MarcelKrüger That is very comprehensive! Thank you!