# Creating symbols: $\oeq$ and $\oneq$

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How do I create my own custom symbols?

I want to make a symbol similar to that of `$\otimes,\ominus$`, etc. It should be an equals sign enclosed by a circle, and also a slashed equals sign enclosed by a circle. Preferrably, the code should read `$\oeq$` and `$\oneq$`, or something similar.

---

Thank you for your answers, they were very beneficial.

I am, so far, satisfied with the following definition for `$\oeq$`:

```
\newcommand\opn{\mathrel{\ooalign{$-$\cr
  \hidewidth\raise.45ex\hbox{$-$}\cr}}}
\newcommand\oeqq{\mathrel{\ooalign{$\opn$\cr
  \hidewidth\raise.21ex\hbox{$\ocircle\mkern.0mu$}\cr}}}
\newcommand{\oeq}{\mathrel{\lower.22ex\hbox{$\oeqq$}}}
```

Could anyone use this definition to obtain similarly `$\oneq$`, with the slash fully inside the circle?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While there is `\olessthan` in the `stmaryrd` package, there's nothing predefined for your `\oeq` and `\oneq` in the usually recommended Comprehensive List of LaTeX symbols.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{mathtools,wasysym,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\oo@ocircle[5]{\mathrel{\ooalign{\hfil\raisebox{#1\height}{\scalebox{#2}{$#4#5$}}\hfil\cr$#4#3$}}}
\newcommand\oneqx{\mathpalette{\oo@ocircle{0.025}{0.95}{\ocircle}}{\neq}}
\newcommand\oeq{\mathpalette{\oo@ocircle{0.025}{0.95}{\ocircle}}{=}}
\newcommand\oneq{\mathpalette{\oo@ocircle{0.025}{0.95}{\oslash}}{=}}
\newcommand\olt{\mathpalette{\oo@ocircle{0.06}{0.87}{\ocircle}}{\mkern-2mu<}}
\newcommand\ogt{\mathpalette{\oo@ocircle{0.06}{0.87}{\ocircle}}{>\mkern-2mu}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[ \text{\ttfamily\ \ oeq: }A \oeq B_{A \oeq B_{A \oeq B}} \]
\[ \text{\ttfamily oneqx: }A \oneqx B_{A \oneqx B_{A \oneqx B}} \]
\[ \text{\ttfamily\ oneq: }A \oneq B_{A \oneq B_{A \oneq B}} \]
\[ \text{\ttfamily\ \ olt: }A \olt B_{A \olt B_{A \olt B}} \]
\[ \text{\ttfamily\ \ ogt: }A \ogt B_{A \ogt B_{A \ogt B}} \]

\end{document}
```

Remarks:

- There's proper empty `\ocircle` in the package `wasysym`, one that matches `oplus` etc.
- For the explanation of the code, this is a good reading: [\subseteq + \circ as a single symbol ("open subset")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/subseteq-circ-as-a-single-symbol-open-subset/22375#22375)
- Since I was digged in the problem, I made matching `\olt` and `\ogt` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a stab at it; it doesn't match the rule thickness contained in `\oplus` and `\ominus` though, nor does it bound the negation to the circle:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\oeq}{\mathrel{\text{\textcircled{$=$}}}}
\newcommand{\oneq}{\mathrel{\text{\textcircled{$\neq$}}}}
\begin{document}
$a \oplus b \ominus c$ \par
$a = b \neq c \oeq d \oneq e$ \par
\end{document}
```

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\text` allows for ease-of-use when these relations are in super-/subscripts.

Comment: there's `\ocircle` in `wasysym`