# Adding symbols at the end(s) of a horizontal line

Tags: symbols, arrows

I'm looking for variations of the symbol `\relbar`, or any other horizontal line that is about as along as a standard-length arrow.

In particular, I'd like to be able to add arrowheads, as in `\leftarrow`, `\rightarrow`, `\leftrightarrow`.

I also wish to be able to add vertical bars, as in `\leftfootline` from the `MnSymbol` package.

Symbols for all of the above exist, but the problem is being able to add them in any combination. For instance, a rightarrow with a vertical bar on the right hand side. This yields 16 possible symbols in total.

Ideas, anyone?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question but isn't a `\relbar` with an arrowhead the same as a `\rightarrow`/`\leftarrow`? And adding vertical bars yields the `\mapsto`/`\mapsfrom` symbols? And vertical bars without the heads is `\vdash`/`\dashv`...

Comment: `\relbar` is just a minus sign treated as a binary relation symbol, but it should never be used alone, as it is "smashed", so it has no height.

Comment: @elemakil Well yes but they're aren't all from the same "set". They look different. Also, some combinations are missing. Like what about right arrow with a vertical line on the right hand side?

Comment: @user18921 with some resizing for the `..dash..` macros they look pretty consistent I'd say... but I must admit there's no vertical bar on the same side as the arrowhead. Btw. now I do understand how your count yielded 16... ;) But I must agree with @egreg, `\relbar` is not meant to be used for what you're trying to achieve, maybe think about using `TikZ` for creating those symbols.

Comment: @elemakil I'm not committed to using `\relbar`, so any other solution is fine. I just want them all to look similar. Are you suggesting I should look into TikZ? What is it?

Comment: I had a look at TikZ and it seems pretty powerful. Is it hard to learn? I don't want to spend days trying to figure this out.

Comment: TikZ has a learning curve similar to basketball http://www.cockeyed.com/lessons/learning_curve/learning_curve.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can use TikZ; this is a prototype with a perhaps convenient syntax where the argument to `\erelbar` consists of two digits (0, 1, 2, or 3):

- 0 stands for no arrowhead
- 1 stands for a normal arrowhead
- 2 stands for a bar
- 3 stands for both bar and arrowhead

The first digit refers to the left side, the second one to the right side.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@erelb@r[1]{%
  \mathrel{\tikz[baseline=-.5ex]\draw[#1] (0,0)--(0.3,0);}
}
% 0 is for nothing
% 1 is for arrowhead
% 2 is for bar
% 3 is for both
\newcommand{\erelbar}[1]{\@erelbar#1}
\def\@erelbar#1#2{%
  \ifcase\numexpr#1*4+#2\relax
    \@erelb@r{-}\or     % 00
    \@erelb@r{->}\or    % 01
    \@erelb@r{-|}\or    % 02
    \@erelb@r{->|}\or   % 03
    \@erelb@r{<-}\or    % 10
    \@erelb@r{<->}\or   % 11
    \@erelb@r{<-|}\or   % 12
    \@erelb@r{<->}\or   % 13
    \@erelb@r{|-}\or    % 20
    \@erelb@r{|->}\or   % 21
    \@erelb@r{|-|}\or   % 22
    \@erelb@r{|<->|}\or % 23
    \@erelb@r{|<-}\or   % 30
    \@erelb@r{|<->}\or  % 31
    \@erelb@r{|<-|}\or  % 32
    \@erelb@r{|<->|}    % 33
  \else
    \@wrong
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

$a\erelbar{11}b$

$\begin{array}{cccc}
\erelbar{00} & \erelbar{10} & \erelbar{20} & \erelbar{30} \\
\erelbar{01} & \erelbar{11} & \erelbar{21} & \erelbar{31} \\
\erelbar{02} & \erelbar{12} & \erelbar{22} & \erelbar{32} \\
\erelbar{03} & \erelbar{13} & \erelbar{23} & \erelbar{33} \\
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is neat! I must start learning `TikZ`! One thing though, the resulting arrows have a different size than the arrows created by `LaTeX`'s `\...arrow` commands. They have correct length but are about the half height.

Comment: @elemakil I too. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert in using `TikZ` (which I guess offers by far more tools for creating new symbols), thus I present you my very own `\mapsto` command as an example how one can combine existing `LaTeX` symbols. First the MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\mymapsto{\mathrel{\ooalign{$\rightarrow$\cr%
  \kern-.15ex\raise.275ex\hbox{\scalebox{1}[0.522]{$\mid$}}\cr}}}

\begin{document}
    $\mymapsto$
\end{document}
```

and the resulting symbol:

[image: result]

obviously the vertical bar is longer than for the original `\mapsto` but from what you said I assumed that you intend the vertical bars to share the height of the arrowhead.

Now take another look at the MWE, in the definition of the `\mymapsto` command I superimposed a `\rightarrow` with a `\mid` (using `\ooalign` see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/subseteq-circ-as-a-single-symbol-open-subset/22375#22375) answer for a quick course on `\ooalign`). Obviously there's a lot of work required when determining the correct dimensions of `\kern` and `\raise`, however, using my code as basis you should be able to construct the 15 remaining symbols yourself [don't forget `\rotatebox`, it will be useful!]. I'd like to stress that you should use the units `em` or `ex` when constructing a symbol because when doing so the symbols will remain correct for different fontsizes (or so I'm told).

In constract to using `TikZ` this solution might be a little less time-consuming, but you won't learn something new in the process I guess...