# Dash at the end/beginning of a harpoon arrow

Tags: arrows, punctuation

I need to insert a harpoon arrow up with a dash, that can be both at the beginning or at the end of the arrow.

I've found [this method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96382/4427) but it only allows me to insert normal arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@erelb@r[1]{%
  \mathrel{\tikz[baseline=-.5ex]\draw[#1] (0,0)--(0.3,0);}
}
% 0 is for nothing
% 1 is for arrowhead
% 2 is for bar
% 3 is for both
\newcommand{\erelbar}[1]{\@erelbar#1}
\def\@erelbar#1#2{%
  \ifcase\numexpr#1*4+#2\relax
    \@erelb@r{-}\or     % 00
    \@erelb@r{->}\or    % 01
    \@erelb@r{-|}\or    % 02
    \@erelb@r{->|}\or   % 03
    \@erelb@r{<-}\or    % 10
    \@erelb@r{<->}\or   % 11
    \@erelb@r{<-|}\or   % 12
    \@erelb@r{<->}\or   % 13
    \@erelb@r{|-}\or    % 20
    \@erelb@r{|->}\or   % 21
    \@erelb@r{|-|}\or   % 22
    \@erelb@r{|<->|}\or % 23
    \@erelb@r{|<-}\or   % 30
    \@erelb@r{|<->}\or  % 31
    \@erelb@r{|<-|}\or  % 32
    \@erelb@r{|<->|}    % 33
  \else
    \@wrong
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

$a\erelbar{11}b$

$\begin{array}{cccc}
\erelbar{00} & \erelbar{10} & \erelbar{20} & \erelbar{30} \\
\erelbar{01} & \erelbar{11} & \erelbar{21} & \erelbar{31} \\
\erelbar{02} & \erelbar{12} & \erelbar{22} & \erelbar{32} \\
\erelbar{03} & \erelbar{13} & \erelbar{23} & \erelbar{33} \\
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

I've tried to use

```
\@erelb@r{|\righthaproonup}    % 33
```

but the output is just this: -

Comment: Where did you find the code? And what's `\@erelb@r` supposed to do? By the way, it's “harpoon”, not “haproon”.

Comment: @egreg seems like you wrote that code :) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96330/adding-symbols-at-the-ends-of-a-horizontal-line

Comment: @Marijn Doh! 

Answer (score 2):

Change the code into

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@erelb@r[1]{%
  \mathrel{\tikz[baseline=-.5ex,>={Classical TikZ Rightarrow[harpoon]}]\draw[#1] (0,0)--(0.3,0);}
}
% 0 is for nothing
% 1 is for arrowhead
% 2 is for bar
% 3 is for both
\newcommand{\erelbar}[1]{\@erelbar#1}
\def\@erelbar#1#2{%
  \ifcase\numexpr#1*4+#2\relax
    \@erelb@r{-}\or     % 00
    \@erelb@r{->}\or    % 01
    \@erelb@r{-|}\or    % 02
    \@erelb@r{->|}\or   % 03
    \@erelb@r{<-}\or    % 10
    \@erelb@r{<->}\or   % 11
    \@erelb@r{<-|}\or   % 12
    \@erelb@r{<->}\or   % 13
    \@erelb@r{|-}\or    % 20
    \@erelb@r{|->}\or   % 21
    \@erelb@r{|-|}\or   % 22
    \@erelb@r{|<->|}\or % 23
    \@erelb@r{|<-}\or   % 30
    \@erelb@r{|<->}\or  % 31
    \@erelb@r{|<-|}\or  % 32
    \@erelb@r{|<->|}    % 33
  \else
    \@wrong
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

$a\erelbar{11}b$

$\begin{array}{cccc}
\erelbar{00} & \erelbar{10} & \erelbar{20} & \erelbar{30} \\
\erelbar{01} & \erelbar{11} & \erelbar{21} & \erelbar{31} \\
\erelbar{02} & \erelbar{12} & \erelbar{22} & \erelbar{32} \\
\erelbar{03} & \erelbar{13} & \erelbar{23} & \erelbar{33} \\
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]