# How to make a circular arrow have the same size and position as other circular symbols?

Tags: spacing, symbols

I'm using the `mathabx` package's circular arrows; however, since I otherwise prefer the usual `amsmath` symbols, I'm following the setup described in  [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386) to import only the circular arrows.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{<5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
<10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rcirclearrow}{0}{mathb}{'367}

\begin{document}
$A\mathbin{\raisebox{0.05ex}{\scalebox{0.9}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{$\rcirclearrow$}}}} B$

$A\otimes B$
\end{document}
```

This is what is produced:

[image: image description]

As you can see, they are not lined up, even though I put the circular arrow inside `\mathbin{}`. Since I know that fiddling with `\hspace` and `\raisebox` is not fully "proper", and won't scale with changes to font or font size, my question is:

> How can I make this circular arrow agree with other circular symbols like `\oplus` and `\otimes`, in a way that will scale properly? Is there a way to figure out the exact value needed to give to `\scalebox` to get the circular arrow to be the same size as an `\otimes`?

Incidentally, I suppose this raises the mathematical question of whether the circular arrow is to be considered a relation or an operator. In my context, I am using

```
 A (right-facing circular arrow) B
```

to mean "`A` acts on `B`". For example, we might have a group `G` acting on a space `X`.

Can any mathematically-inclined people give their opinions/reasoning for whether "acts on" is a relation or operation, and hence whether I should instead be giving the circular arrow a `\mathrel` or a `\mathbin` spacing?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You loose horizontal space by scaling it at `0.9` of its original width. Besides that, I have defined the original `\rcirclearrow` as an `\mathbin`. The `0` you put there made it an Ord atom.

Putting the new symbol inside a box wide as the `\rcirclearrow` symbol you can achieve good results.

#### Reference

- [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)
- [“A quick course on `\ooalign`”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/16595)
- [The mysteries of \mathpalette](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34393/16595)

### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,calc}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{<5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
<10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\rcirclearrow}{\mathbin}{mathb}{'367}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\Rcirclearrow}{\mathpalette\@Rcirclearrow{}}
\newcommand*{\@Rcirclearrow}[1]{%
    \mathbin{\ooalign{\hphantom{$#1\rcirclearrow$}\cr\hss\raisebox{0.05ex}{%
                \scalebox{0.9}{%
                    \rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{%
                        $#1\rcirclearrow$}}}\hss}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\leavevmode\llap{\smash{\rule[-2.3\baselineskip]{.4pt}{2.5\baselineskip}}}% only to show the alignment
$A \rcirclearrow B_{A \rcirclearrow B_{A \rcirclearrow B}}$%
\rlap{\smash{\rule[-2.3\baselineskip]{.4pt}{2.5\baselineskip}}}% again, only for alignment

$A \Rcirclearrow B_{A \Rcirclearrow B_{A \Rcirclearrow B}}$

$A \otimes B_{A \otimes B_{A \otimes B}}$
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]