# Not equal sign (≠) with a vertical bar

Tags: math-mode, symbols, relation-symbols

Is it possible to get a `\neq` but with a vertical bar instead of a slanted one? There are inequality operators like AMS's `\gvertneqq` that feature this kind of "not equal" but not without mixing it with other signs.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a&\gvertneqq b\\
C&\neq \varnothing
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: result of the above code]

So what I basically would like to have is the isolated symbol under the > in the `\gvertneqq` above. Particularly because I don't like the different slopes of the slashes in the second line and "≠∅" is quite a common combination.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Equal sign with vertical line

The vertical line `|` is a little tall for my taste. The following definition for `\vneq` decreases the total height of the vertical line to match the total height of `\neq`. Resizing vertical height will not change the line thickness in horizontal direction.

- The final witdh and height of the vertical line can be fine-tuned by redefining macros `\vneqxscale` and `\vneqyscale`. The default is `1`.
- `\mathpalette` allows the symbol to resize automatically.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}% \varnothing

\usepackage{graphicx}% \resizebox
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\vneq}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\@vneq{=}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@vneq}[2]{%
  % #1: math style (\displaystyle, \textstyle, ...)
  % #2: symbol (=, ...)
  \sbox0{\raisebox{\depth}{$#1\neq$}}%
  \sbox2{\raisebox{\depth}{$#1|\m@th$}}%
  \ifdim\ht2>\ht0 %
    \sbox2{\resizebox{\vneqxscale\width}{\vneqyscale\ht0}{\unhbox2}}%
  \fi
  \sbox2{$\m@th#1\vcenter{\copy2}$}%
  \ooalign{%
    \hfil\phantom{\copy2}\hfil\cr
    \hfil$#1#2\m@th$\hfil\cr
    \hfil\copy2\hfil\cr
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\vneqxscale}{1}
\newcommand*{\vneqyscale}{1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  % Comparison \neq vs. vneq
  \varnothing \neq \emptyset \vneq \varnothing \\
\] 
\[ 
  % Check sizes:
  \vneq^{\vneq^{\vneq}} \\
\] 
\[ 
  % Bounding box checks:
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}
  \fbox{$\neq$}\,\fbox{$\vneq$}\,\fbox{$|$}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The height can be further decreased, e.g.

```
\renewcommand*{\vneqyscale}{.8}
```

> [image: Result/.8]

Result for `mathabx`:

> [image: mathabx]

Result for `txfonts`:

> [image: txfonts]

Result for `MnSymbol`:

> [image: MnSymbol]

Here the vertical line is too thick and the horizontal resizing needs shrinking:

```
\renewcommand*{\vneqxscale}{.67}
```

Result for `MnSymbol` and `\vneqxscale` = `.67`:

> [image: MnSymbol/.67]

### Alternative to `varnothing`

Instead of changing `\neq`, the empty set symbol `\varnothing` could be constructed using `\not` to match the slope of the slanted vertical lines.
However, `\circ` is too small and `\bigcirc`too big. Therefore this method is shown for `txfonts` that provides `\medcirc` and `MnSymbol` with `\medcircle`.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{txfonts}
%\newcommand*{\varemptysetcircle}{\medcirc}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\newcommand*{\varemptysetcircle}{\medcircle}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\varemptyset}{%
  {% mathord
    \vphantom{\not=}% correct height and depth of the final symbol
    \mathpalette\@varemptyset\varemptysetcircle
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@varemptyset}[2]{%
  % #1: math style (\displaystyle, \textstyle, ...)
  % #2: circle
  \ooalign{%
    \hfil$\m@th#1\not\hphantomeq$\hfil\cr
    \hfil$\m@th#1#2$\hfil\cr
  }%
}
% \not can be redefined to take an argument
\newcommand*{\hphantomeq}{%
  \mathrel{\hphantom{=}}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\[
  \not=\; \color{blue}\neq \varemptyset\; \color{black}\varnothing
\]
\end{document}
```

Result for `txfonts`:

> [image: txfonts]

Result for `MnSymbol`:

> [image: MnSymbol]

Comment: This is just an amazing answer! I hope Werner won't mind that I couldn't but change the accepted answer to this one. I'm having some trouble when trying to `\renewcommand` `\neq` to this version of `\vneq` though. More specifically, I get a "TeX capacity exceeded". Any idea why?

Comment: `\vneq is using `\neq` in macro `\@vneq`. Thus you can store the old meaning: `\let\ltxneq=\neq` and use `\ltxneq` in `\@vneq`. Then you should be able to redefine `\neq`.

Answer (score 22):

Yes:

[image: screenshot of code below]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\vneq{\mathrel{\ooalign{$=$\cr\hidewidth$|$\hidewidth\cr}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a&\gvertneqq b\\
C&\neq \varnothing \\
d&\vneq f
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

For a motivation behind the commands in `\vneq`, read egreg's excellent tutorial on `\ooalign` in [`\subseteq` + `\circ` as a single symbol (“open subset”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/5764)

Answer (score 10):

A simplistic solution would be

```
\usepackage{mathabx}
\changenotsign
```

but this would mean changing a great part of the math symbols, which is not desirable as, in my opinion, some of the symbols provided by `mathabx` are badly designed.

A solution with standard tools is

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\neq{\mathrel{\vphantom{|}\mathpalette\xsneq\relax}}
\newcommand\xsneq[2]{%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth$#1|$\hidewidth\cr$#1=$\cr}%
}

\begin{document}
$a\neq b$
\end{document}
```

I used `\renewcommand` because it will be simply a matter of removing that code in order to revert `\neq` to its usual shape.

By using `\mathpalette`, the created symbol will become smaller in subscripts or superscripts.

[image]

Comment: both this symbol and an equals sign with a back-slanted cancellation are included in the stix fonts.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, but those fonts don't mix well with Computer Modern and other fonts.

Comment: sad but true.  they were designed to mix with times, which was the consensus typeface of the stipub consortium members.