# How do I create a vertical version of \not?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

If I wanted `\not<` but with vertical strikethrough rather than a diagonal strikethrough, how would I make it?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20613/18228?

Comment: @HerrK. Close, but it's horizontal, not vertical

Comment: And this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108193/not-equal-sign-%e2%89%a0-with-a-vertical-bar?rq=1 (seems better than mine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand\vnotless{\mathrel{<\mkern-8mu\mid\mkern8mu}}

\begin{document}
    $a \vnotless b$
\end{document}
```

For sure there are better ways, but this works as a dirty-n-fast method...

[image]

Comment: And you could also separate out a `\vnot` command through `\mkern-8mu\mid\mkern8mu` then, right?

Comment: Yes, something like `\newcommand{\vnot}[1]{\mathrel{#1\mkern-8mu\mid\mkern8mu}}` should more or less work, but depending on the operator may need adjustments...

Answer (score 4):

A version which more or less scales correctly in math styles (not quite perfect, though...)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for \binrel@
\usepackage{amssymb} % for \lessgtr as test

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\vnot}[2][0]{\def\@tempa{\mkern#1mu}\binrel@{#2}\binrel@@{\mathpalette\vnot@{#2}}}
\newcommand*{\vnot@}[2]{%
   {\m@th\ooalign{\hidewidth$#1\@tempa|$\hidewidth\cr$#1#2$}}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a \vnot[1]{<} b$
$\scriptstyle a \vnot[1]{<} b$
$\scriptscriptstyle a \vnot[1]{<} b$
\par
$a<b$
$\scriptstyle a<b$
$\scriptscriptstyle a<b$

\smallskip
$a \vnot{\lessgtr} b$
$\scriptstyle a \vnot{\lessgtr} b$
$\scriptscriptstyle a \vnot{\lessgtr} b$
\par
$a\lessgtr b$
$\scriptstyle a\lessgtr b$
$\scriptscriptstyle a\lessgtr b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The horizontal placing is tricky, because the "absolute center" might not be optically ideal. I let a small kern to be added through the optional parameter.

```
$a \vnot{<} b$\par
$a \vnot[1]{<} b$\par
$a \vnot[2]{<} b$
```

[image]

Comment: Much better than mine, yes!

Comment: @Rmano "Better" is relative. Yours works for the particular symbol, and always will; mine tries to work in general, and manual tweaking will thus be necessary. I'm not sure which is "better"...

Comment: @campa I'm not sure whether using `\binrel@` is really needed, as it seems unlikely to negate an operation symbol. Anyway, nice answer!

Comment: @egreg The thought crossed my mind when I was done writing the answer, but then I've decided to leave it. Worst-case scenario it's useless, but not wrong.