# How to create subset with sim symbol

Tags: symbols, amsmath, math-operators

I've been trying to typeset as an operator the symbol ⫇ (`\subset` on top a `\sim`), but the following solutions have not been helpful

- ⫇ does not seem to be listed in symbols-a4.pdf, so detexify does not find it.
- `\limits` and `\underset` puts the tilde (or `\sim`) too separated from `\subset`.
- Using `\undertilde` looks ugly.

Is any other option to obtain this symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapting [egreg's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/21591):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\subsetsim{\mathrel{%
  \ooalign{\raise0.2ex\hbox{$\subset$}\cr\hidewidth\raise-0.8ex\hbox{\scalebox{0.9}{$\sim$}}\hidewidth\cr}}}
\begin{document}
\[
  A \subsetsim B
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Adapt the parameters to your likings.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a straight-forward way using `\substack` from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand\subsetsim{\mathrel{\substack{
  \textstyle\subset\\[-0.2ex]\textstyle\sim}}}
\begin{document}
\[ f(x) \subset g(x) \subseteq h(x) \subsetsim i(x) \sim j(x) \]
\end{document}
```

The definition could be updated to accommodate usage in sub-/superscripts as well.

Comment: I think this one looks better than the solution suggested from @mafp, because the tilde does not go so far under the baseline.

Answer (score 4):

A you have noticed the symbol is in Unicode as  ⫇  (U+2AC7) so if you are using xetex or luatex and unicode-math it would just work. It's also in the STIX fonts of which there is a beta release now with support for classic TeX: http://www.stixfonts.org/

Comment: But what about other symbols which are not in unicode like `\sqsubset` over `\sim`?

Comment: @fbanados you didn't ask about those:-) You always have the option of constructing a symbol as the other answers show, but If a symbol is shown to be used in published documents it could also be put forward for inclusion in Unicode. Having a real symbol has benefits in terms of speed rendering and cutting/pasting to other systems, not least the web.

Answer (score 3):

### Poor man's solution

The following example constructs the symbol ⫇ by putting `\sim` below `\subset`.
The `\sim` is set in a smaller font, if the current math style is `\displaystyle` or `\textstyle`, then `\scriptstyle` is used for `\sim`, if the current math style is `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle` then `\scriptscriptstyle` is used for `\sim`. Since in the latter case the font is not smaller, this solution works for `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, and `\scriptstyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}  

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\subsetsim}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathchoice
    {\@subsetsim\displaystyle\scriptstyle}%
    {\@subsetsim\textstyle\scriptstyle}%
    {\@subsetsim\scriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle}%
    {\@subsetsim\scriptscriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle}%
  }%
}   
\newcommand*{\@subsetsim}[2]{%
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1\subset$}%
  \sbox2{$\m@th#2\sim$}%
  \sbox4{$\m@th#2$}%
  \raisebox{.5\dimexpr\ht2-\ht4\relax}{% 
    \oalign{\copy0 \cr\hidewidth\copy2\hidewidth}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\[ a \subset a \sim a \subsetsim a - a_{b \subsetsim b_{c \subsetsim c}} \]

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Remarks:

- The minus shows the math axis.
- In the latest case (c ⫇ c) the `\sim` is a little too large because the expression is set in `\scriptscriptstyle`, see above.