# Logical equivalence vDashv

Tags: symbols, logic

I need to create a symbol logical equivalence. Contact vDash with appropriate vertical line, but I can not find any. Can you advise?

Comment: the package `mathabx` has both `\Dashv` and `\vDash` is this what you mean?

Comment: is this the same as unicode U+29E6, "gleich stark = tautological equivalent"?  if so, that is in the stix and xits fonts.

Answer (score 4):

While `mathabx` has some symbols that might help, using it means changing *all* symbol fonts and this, in general, is not desirable.

Here's a possible way to do it: superimpose a `\vDash` symbol to its reflected copy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}
\newcommand{\Dashv}{%
  \mathrel{\text{\reflectbox{$\vDash$}}}%
}
\newcommand{\vDashv}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \text{%
      \ooalign{$\vDash$\cr\reflectbox{$\vDash$}\cr}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
$f\vDash g$

$f\Dashv g$

$f\vDashv g$
\end{document}
```

I've also defined a `\Dashv` command with the reflected symbol.

[image]

See [\subseteq + \circ as a single symbol ("open subset")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/subseteq-circ-as-a-single-symbol-open-subset) for a quick introduction to `\ooalign`.

Comment: just asking, but does the resulting symbol denote logical equivalence? I found some occurrences of `=||=` (which would be obtained with `\Dashv\vDash` from mathabx but never something like `|=|`.

Comment: @dcmst I don't know; that's how I interpreted the question. On the other hand, there's no ‘official’ symbol for logical equivalence and anybody is free to choose their own.

Comment: Even if there is no official way =||= would be what logicians would understand (and I have seen a few times). An alternative would be to write \vDash f \equiv g (assuming the Deduction Theorem holds).

Comment: @dcmst Would it be like the two symbols separated by a thin space?

Comment: In my tentative understanding of the question, the OP wanted a `=||=` like symbol, exactly as it is rendered by `\Dashv\vDash` (with matabhx) with no customization. But you have a point, because after re-reading the question, that word "contact" made me reconsider my initial understanding. Maybe the OP will be more specific after he sees your answer.

Comment: @egreg -- please see my comment to the original question.  if this is the answer, please get in touch off-line because i have a question about the shape.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what is meant? 'Logical equivalence' can mean a number of things so I'm trying to go by the description but am not very clear (like everyone else).

[image: A turnstile]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{turnstile}

\begin{document}

\[
    P \wedge Q\  \ssststile{}{}\ \sim(\sim P \vee \sim Q)
\]    

\end{document}
```

This is not really a symbol for logical equivalence as logicians usually mean it, but if it is anything like a `\vdash`, I think it must be something along these lines. In case that's not what is required, the `turnstile` package is almost certain to provide the symbol which is desired here. It can produce very many varieties of turnstile.

EDIT: Actually, I just realised it was `\vDash` rather than `\vdash` so maybe:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{turnstile}

\begin{document}

\[
    P \wedge Q\  \sdststile{}{}\ \sim(\sim P \vee \sim Q)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: A different turnstile]

Here's an article about [the project](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/turnstile/turnstile-en/turnstile_article.pdf) (linked from CTAN also).

Answer (score 0):

PlainTeX defines macro `\models` by

```
\def\models{\mathrel|\joinrel=}
```

You can define your own symbol – say `\tequiv` – by

```
\def\tequiv{\mathrel|\joinrel=\joinrel\mathrel|}
```