# LaTeX \models symbol that goes both ways

Tags: math-mode, symbols, logic

Is there a LaTeX symbol for `\models` that goes both ways? All I need is another vertical line at the end.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144340/121799)?

Answer (score 6):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mymod}{\models\!\mid}
\begin{document}
\[
A \mymod B
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Set a new `math` `rel`ation that `join`s `\models` and `\rvert`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\modelsm}{\mathrel{\models\joinrel\rvert}}

\begin{document}

$A \modelsm B$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It’s in `unicode-math`, `stix` and `stix2` as `\gleichstark`.  The Unicode symbol ⧦ is U+29E6.  The default math font, Latin Modern Math, does not contain it as of January 2019, but many others do.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchUppercase}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}[Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}
\( \sigma \gleichstark \tau \)
\end{document}
```

[image: σ⧦τ]