# Is \mathrel always needed?

Tags: math-mode, relation-symbols

I answered another question ([LaTeX \models symbol that goes both ways](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471593/latex-models-symbol-that-goes-both-ways)) creating a new symbol, a relation, without using `\mathrel`.

In his answer to the same question, Werner used it (he also used `\joinrel`, a command I didn't know, where I used `\!`).

In this case, however, I see no difference in the results with or without `\mathrel`. Is it always needed?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\newcommand{\mymod}{\mathrel{\models\!\mid}} 
\newcommand{\mymode}{\models\!\mid} 
\newcommand{\mymodel}{\mathrel{\models\joinrel\mid}} 
\begin{document} 
This is without \verb|\mathrel|, with \verb|\!|:
\[ A \mymod B\quad {\scriptstyle  A \mymod B }\quad  {\scriptscriptstyle  A \mymod B }\] 
This is with \verb|\mathrel|, with \verb|\!|:
\[ A \mymode B\quad {\scriptstyle  A \mymode B }\quad  {\scriptscriptstyle  A \mymode B } \] 
This is with \verb|\mathrel| and \verb|\joinrel|:
\[ A \mymodel B \quad {\scriptstyle  A \mymodel B }\quad  {\scriptscriptstyle  A \mymodel B }\] 
They seem the same to me. What is the difference?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\!` does `\mskip-\thinmuskip` where `\thinmuskip=3mu`, whereas `\joinrel` does `\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}`, so if the atoms on both sides of `\joinrel` are also rel atoms, the two commands are equivalent.

Comment: `\mathrel` like `\mathbin` etc. adjust the "class" of the following group. The different groups are described in the TeX Book. It's basically to tell the system the semantics of your symbol.

Comment: @TeXnician but in this case probably the "class" is already correct, isn't it?

Comment: I actually don't know in which classes `\mid` and `\models` are but as the spacing seems correct it is probably `\mathbin` or `\mathrel`. The only semantic difference is that you now do not have one relation but actually two following each other (models and mid). I don't know whether this might have any side effects on the spacing but I think that, as long as you are not adding any groups inbetween, you are safe.

Comment: @TeXnician Thank you, your thought is correct, see Henri's answer :)

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else who wants to use this symbol, it’s in `unicode-math`, `stix` and `stix2` as `\gleichstark`.

Comment: And in Unicode as ⧦.

Comment: @Davislor Thank you, just upvoted your answer to the original question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can figure out what is going on using the table on page 170 of the TeXbook.

> [image]
>
> Here 0, 1, 2, and 3 stand for no space, thin space, medium space, and thick space, respectively; the table entry is parenthesized if the space is to be inserted only in display and text styles, not in script and scriptscript styles.

First we look at the definitions of `\models`, `\mid`, `\!`, and `\joinrel`.  For simplicity I use the definitions from Plain TeX (the LaTeX definitions are similar but with some extra `\protect` and stuff).

```
\def\models{\mathrel|\joinrel=}
\mathchardef\mid="326A
\def\!{\mskip-\thinmuskip} % \thinmuskip=3mu
\def\joinrel{\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}}
```

Checking in the table the spacing between a Rel and a Rel atom we find `0`, i.e. no spacing at all.  That means that there will be no space inserted between any of the atoms in any of the following sequences because all the atoms are Rel (except `\mskip` which is not an atom)

```
\models\!\mid
\models\joinrel\mid
```

Because the leftmost and rightmost atoms in these sequences are of type Rel, the whole sequence will behave like a Rel atom (with respect to spacing).  So in this case the enclosing `\mathrel` is redundant.

Answer (score 11):

#### The ugly

```
\newcommand{\mymodel}{\mathrel{\models\joinrel\mid}}
```

#### The bad

```
\newcommand{\mymod}{\mathrel{\models\!\mid}} 
\newcommand{\mymode}{\models\!\mid}
```

#### The good

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\models\joinrel\mid}
```

#### The best™

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\xjoinrel}{\mathrel{\mkern-3.5mu}}
\let\models\relax % undefine \models
\DeclareRobustCommand{\models}{\mathrel{|}\xjoinrel\Relbar} %% YES!
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mymod}{\mathrel{|}\xjoinrel\Relbar\xjoinrel\mathrel{|}}
```

#### Explanations

TeX never adds space between two consecutive relation symbols. Since `\models` is defined as `\mathrel{|}\joinrel\Relbar` and all three are relation symbols, the first method has a redundant `\mathrel`.

The command `\joinrel` is `\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}`. Using `\mid` and `\mathrel{|}` is the same, but in this context `\mathrel{|}` is better because `\mid` might be used for a different symbol.

Why are the other two bad? Because `\!` is not the right spacing.

The good is just what's needed, because it gives a relation and adds no spaces in between.

The best method avoids the little gap between the `\Relbar` and `\mid`. Look closely in the table below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\xjoinrel}{\mathrel{\mkern-3.5mu}}

\renewcommand{\models}{%
  \mathrel{|}
  \xjoinrel
  \Relbar 
}
\newcommand{\modeledby}{%
  \Relbar 
  \xjoinrel
  \mathrel{|}
}
\newcommand{\doublemodels}{%
  \mathrel{|}
  \xjoinrel
  \Relbar 
  \xjoinrel
  \mathrel{|}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
New & Old \\
\midrule
$A\models B$ & $A\mid\joinrel\Relbar B$ \\
$A\modeledby B$ & $A \Relbar\joinrel\mid B$ \\
$A\doublemodels B$ & $A \mid\joinrel\Relbar\joinrel\mid B$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Eventually, are you saying the current `\models` is not perfect?

Comment: @CarLaTeX I dare to! `;-)` Besides, there are better symbols in `amssymb`.

Comment: It has been very difficult to choose which answer to accept. I accepted Henri's one because it is more focalized on the general problem rather than the specific symbol. Moreover: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7463/101651 :)