# \nearrow and \swarrow together

Tags: math-mode, arrows

I'm trying to get an arrow that has an arrow head pointing north east and south west, so like `\updownarrow` but rotated. I can't seem to find this in LaTeX at all. It has to go inside an `equation` environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Considering `\neswarrow` is in the `MnSymbol` package, and can be found in the Comprehensive Symbol list this is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-alphabet

Answer (score 20):

The powerful `\ooalign` wins; TeX is able to figure out the widths itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\neswarrow}{%
  \mathrel{\text{\ooalign{$\swarrow$\cr$\nearrow$}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$a\neswarrow b_{\neswarrow}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

See [\subseteq + \circ as a single symbol ("open subset")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/subseteq-circ-as-a-single-symbol-open-subset/22375#22375) for more information about `\ooalign`.

Comment: Good name for it. The same name that the `MnSymbol` package has. :)

Comment: @masu I just thought that usually North is mentioned before South.

Comment: actually, such an arrow does exist in unicode, as U+2922, so it's in the `stix` and `xits` fonts, but that isn't documented very well yet, certainly not in the comprehensive symbols list or in detexify.  and the shapes of those arrowheads are most likely not sufficiently similar to most other arrowheads that this arrow from one of those fonts wouldn't look out of place.

Answer (score 6):

It is not a perfect solution, but maybe it is enough:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\begin{document}


\newlength\nesw
\settowidth{\nesw}{$\nearrow$}
\def\neswarrow{\nearrow\hspace{-\nesw}\swarrow}

\[
\neswarrow
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That worked a treat! I can't believe that isn't a standard arrow given the plethora of other arrow choices that are standard.

Comment: @user2933038 There are thousands of "standard" symbols. You usually need less than one hundred. Loading all of them would be quite in-efficient, not speaking about problems with name clashes.

Answer (score 2):

This is ⤢ (U+2922) in Unicode and `\neswarrow` in `stix` and `stix2`.  To use it in `unicode-math`, load the symbol from either XITS Math or STIX Two Math, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=\neswarrow, Scale=MatchUppercase]{STIX Two Math}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\[ \neswarrow \]
\end{document}
```

[image: STIX Two sample]