# conventional temperature symbol

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

Looking for a symbol for the thermodynamic concept of `conventional Temperature` corresponding to `\SI{298.15}{\kelvin}` or `\SI{25}{\Celsius}` it is basically an uppercase `T` with a lowercase `c` overlaying it. Couldn't see it in the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List or get it through DeTeXify.

The simplest approximation I have for it is by using the following:

`\rlap{T}c`

which gives the following symbol

[image: Conventional Temperature]

Or define a newcommand to give it `\newcommand{\Tcon}{\rlap{T}c}`

Ideally the `c` should be shifted up from the baseline but it is good for now.

So the question is: Is there already a symbol for conventional temperature?

Comment: I have never seen this symbol before. If there really is none, you can still use Tikz.

Comment: @Johannes_B. I recently came across it myself, I think it may be a makey-uppy symbol. It is used in the textbook 'Physical Chemistry' by P.W. Atkins, a standard text book, maybe he uses it as a shorthand way of expressing the 298.15 K! The above attempt will do me though!

Comment: And should the "T" and "c" be in sans serif?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina No I think they should be serif, but that may just be the font of the textbook. The above image was taken from a beamer slide which had all fonts sans serif.

Comment: @Leeser I checked my copy of Atkins: can't see the symbol. Edition and page(s)?

Comment: It's been a while since I had a copy of Atkins in my hands but I can't remember having ever seen said symbol. I only know `$\theta$` (or `$\vartheta$`) for the temperature and `$T$` for the absolute temperature.

Comment: @josephwright, Edition 4 page 43 it is introduced fro the first time and then appears in Tables, text and problems from there on.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, it appears in both serif and sans serif...Atkins Physical Chemistry ed4 pg 44, sans serif in Table and serif in equation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option, using `\ooalign` (a description of `\ooalign` can be found in **egreg**'s answer to [\subseteq + \circ as a single symbol ("open subset")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/subseteq-circ-as-a-single-symbol-open-subset/22375#22375)). A sans serif and a serif variant are provided:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\convtemp{%
  {\ooalign{T\cr\hfil\raise.2ex\hbox{c}\hfil\cr}}}
\newcommand\Convtemp{%
  {\ooalign{\textsf{T}\cr\hfil\raise.2ex\hbox{\textsf{c}}\hfil\cr}}}

\begin{document}

\convtemp\quad\Convtemp

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Forgot to mention can it be math-like, ie slanted not upright similar to output of $T$, otherwise perfect

Comment: May i ask, where `\ooalign` is documented? I never came across it so far.

Comment: lowlevel command see the following for a good description of how to use it...http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/subseteq-circ-as-a-single-symbol-open-subset/22375#22375  only saw this after Gonzalo's use of `\ooalign`

Comment: Add a pair of braces around `\ooalign{...}` or funny things will happen.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Since `\ooalign` issues `\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen`, this setting should be made local.

Comment: @egreg Yes; I keep forgetting this (even though you warned about this in the answer I linked to).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Conventional temperature is not a variable, but a fixed temperature akin to the triple point of water. \convtemp is 298.15 K so defining something as \SI{45}{\convtemp} doesn't make sense, but I like the way you did it and I now know how to declare a new siunitx unit.

Comment: @Leeser Ah, sorry about that, I've removed the definition as a unit from my answer and I also added a sans serif version.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Although \convtemp is a fixed temp, could you put back up how you assigned it as a variable and declared a new siunitx unit. I think that step was also highly informative and instructional. Maybe a "new variable" say "furlong"...:)

Answer (score 3):

Here, I use `stackengine` to inset the `c` atop the `T`.  The 1st and 3rd arguments `{c}` say to place the inset with respect the horizontal and vertical center of the anchor.  The 2nd argument is the horizontal offset from the center for the inset, the 4th argument is the vertical offset for the inset.  The inset is the 5th argument, and the "anchor" is the last argument.

In the first 4 cases, I vary the size of the `c`.  In the 2nd four cases, I make the `c` sans serif.  I don't know what exactly you seek, but one of these 8 cases might get you on your way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
45 \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{c}{T}\par
45 \stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.2pt}{\small c}{T}\par
45 \stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.2pt}{\footnotesize c}{T}\par
45 \stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.3pt}{\scriptsize c}{T}\par
45 \stackinset{c}{-.2pt}{c}{}{\textsf{c}}{T}\par
45 \stackinset{c}{-.2pt}{c}{-.2pt}{\small \textsf{c}}{T}\par
45 \stackinset{c}{-.2pt}{c}{-.2pt}{\footnotesize \textsf{c}}{T}\par
45 \stackinset{c}{-.2pt}{c}{-.3pt}{\scriptsize \textsf{c}}{T}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]