# How to put bullet symbol on top of downarrow symbol

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I want to put bullet symbol on top of downward arrow symbol. Can someone help me on this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

The transition is represented with $\mathrel{\bullet}\downarrow $ arrow.

\end{document}
```

Edit1: Actually I want to attach bullet symbol on top of downarrow symbol without any gap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't really know what I'm doing with this, but a suggestion with `\ooalign` and `\mathchoice`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\bulletarrow{%
\mathchoice
  {{\ooalign{\raise0.8ex\hbox{$\bullet$}\cr$\downarrow$}}}
  {{\ooalign{\raise0.8ex\hbox{$\bullet$}\cr$\downarrow$}}}
  {{\ooalign{\raise0.65ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\bullet$}\cr$\scriptstyle\downarrow$}}}
  {{\ooalign{\raise0.5ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\bullet$}\cr$\scriptscriptstyle\downarrow$}}}%
}

\begin{document}

The transition is represented with $ \bulletarrow_{\bulletarrow_{\bulletarrow}} $ arrow.
\end{document}
```

For more information about `\ooalign` see [egregs answer to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/subseteq-circ-as-a-single-symbol-open-subset/22375#22375).

Comment: @egreg Wasn't quite able to wrap my head around `\mathpalette` right now. Feel free to modify if I've done anything silly.

Answer (score 7):

I just wanted to share this approach.  The items are stacked to achieve the desired effect, and the `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` macro of the `scalerel` package will automatically import the current mathstyle into the macro, into places where the mathstyle would otherwise be lost.

The length `\LMpt` is a length unit, used inside of the `\ThisStyle` argument, which is 1pt in `\textstyle` and `\displaystyle`, but scales to 0.7pt in `\scriptstyle`, and 0.5pt in `\scriptscriptstyle`, so that the relative stacking lengths remain proportional

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}[2014/03/10]
\def\specsym{\ThisStyle{\stackon[-1\LMpt]{$\SavedStyle\downarrow$}{$\SavedStyle\bullet$}}}
\begin{document}
This is the symbol: \specsym, 
$\specsym$ $\scriptstyle\specsym$ $\scriptscriptstyle\specsym$
\end{document}
```

[image]

One could embrace the macro in a `\mathord` if one desired to use it exclusively in math mode (thanks, egreg).

Thanks also to azetina who, in his answer, makes a good point regarding the use of `stackengine`.  A syntax such as

```
\stackon[-1\LMpt]{$\SavedStyle\downarrow$}{$\SavedStyle\bullet$}
```

is easy to visualize and explain.  Its drawback is that if you use stacks for other functions in your document, this syntax could be inadvertently affected by the setting of various `stackengine` defaults, like alignment, etc.  One way to avoid this problem is to specify the macro in terms of `\stackengine`, which is not affected by the changing of package defaults.  In the current case, that would mean a more obtuse, but also more protected syntax:

```
\stackengine{-1\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle\downarrow$}{$\SavedStyle\bullet$}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}
```

Comment: `\mathop` is a TeX primitive; if you want to force a symbol to be used in math mode, use the correct type: `\mathop`, `\mathrel`, `\mathbin`, `\mathpunct`, `\mathopen`, `\mathclose` or `\mathord`. Probably the last one is what's best in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Using the `stackengine` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\bulletarrow}{%
 \setstackgap{S}{-0.25ex}%
 \mathrel{\Shortstack{{$\bullet$} {$\downarrow$}}}}
\begin{document}
$\bulletarrow$
\end{document}
```

Another possible definition using the `\stackengine` command would be:

```
\stackengine{-0.25ex}{$\downarrow$}{$\bullet$}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}
```

Comment: +1 for the "stack" approach.  See my own answer for a twist on that.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Just saw it. They are your packages so you know best what other approaches exist. Wonderful approach by the way!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\overset` from [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The transition is represent with $\overset{\bullet}{\downarrow}$ arrow.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Can we attach these symbols together? Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: @user1890924 I'm not used I know what you mean by "attach together"; please expand on your question.

Comment: There's a space between the two, so I suppose he wants to remove that.

Comment: I just edited the question before your comment. :)