# Symbol: "maps isomorphically"

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I want to make a symbol for "maps isomorphically" which consists of a relatively large tilde above a right arrow. Overset doesn't work (besides, the tilde would be too small). MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Thus $X$ is isomorphic to $Y$ via $f$: 
\[f : X \overset{\tilde}{\to} Y.\]
\end{document}
```

I also tried using `array` but that didn't work either. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Thus $X$ is isomorphic to $Y$ via $f$: 
\[f: X \begin{array}{c}\tilde \\ \to \end{array} Y\]
```

If I could get this to work, the spacing would need to be adjusted significantly.

Comment: have a look `ooalign`, one of `egreg`'s favourite tools - a tutorial can be found in [\subseteq + \circ as a single symbol ("open subset")](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22371) and in many answers since :)

Comment: What about `\xrightarrow{\sim}` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `\xrightarrow` should work as pointed out by Alex. Here is how to implement this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
{\tiny
Thus $X$ is isomorphic to $Y$ via $f$: 
\[f : X \xrightarrow{\sim} Y.\]
}
{\Large
Thus $X$ is isomorphic to $Y$ via $f$: 
\[f : X \xrightarrow{\sim} Y.\]
}
\end{document}
```

The output is shown for two different font sizes:

[image]

Comment: It's not perfect though. There is a small visual "glitch" which is also visible in the screenshot.