# Placing `\sim` above `\to`, with correct spacing

Tags: arrows, mathematics, xrightarrow

In an [answer to a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196114/135061), it is explained that

```
\xrightarrow{\sim}
```

will produce an arrow pointed to the right with the `\sim` symbol above it (e.g., to indicate that a map is an isomorphism).
However, I'm not satisfied with the spacing of this symbol, as it appears too high above the arrow:

[image: sim arrow]

Is there a way to move it down? Potentially the arrow would have to be widened a little, to prevent `\sim` from touching the arrowhead.

Comment: You could do sth like `\xrightarrow{\,\raisebox{-0.4ex}{$\sim$}\,}`.

Comment: Duplicate?? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479322/too-much-vertical-space-above-xrightarrow

Comment: @marmot: I think you need `\raisebox{-.4ex}[0ex][0ex]{$\sim$}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this with `\stackrel` and `\smash`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\isomto{\stackrel{\sim}{\smash{\longrightarrow}\rule{0pt}{0.4ex}}}

\begin{document}

$f\colon X\isomto Y$

\end{document}
```

Adjust the height as you wish by changing the `0.4ex`. Note also the use of `\colon` for proper spacing of functions.

Or if you prefer a larger `\sim`, try

```
\newcommand\isomto{\stackrel{\textstyle\sim}{\smash{\longrightarrow}\rule{0pt}{0.4ex}}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I add two little answers with an addendum:

**1st proposal**:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\begin{document}

\[f\colon X\overset{\raise-.5ex\hbox{$\sim$}}{\longrightarrow}Y\] 

\end{document}
```

**2nd proposal**:

Using `tikz-cd` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,relsize}
\tikzset{close/.style={outer sep=-1.2pt}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=.3in]
f: X \arrow[r, close,"\mathlarger{\sim}"] & Y
\end{tikzcd}\]
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

**Addendum of the 2020/04/29:** Using `stix` font where exists a specific symbol named `\similarrightarrow`. But there is an inconvenience. The stix font change the fonts of the characters and you not have the CM default font.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
\[f\colon X \similarrightarrow Y\]
\end{document}
```

[image]