# Seeking two headed harpoon symbol

Tags: symbols

There are several answers here about combining symbols, but I still decided to post this one since it is so simple, also maybe there is a ready symbol in some package that someone knows.

I am using

```
\def\paronto{{\rightharpoonup\kern-1.5ex\rightharpoonup\kern.5ex}}
```

which produces things like

[image]

and I have no idea whether it is robust enough - my kernings were adjusted by hand.

Who knows a better way?

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314730/59109) might help?

Comment: @AboAmmar It certainly looks nicer and should behave well in super/subscripts, thank you.

Comment: @AboAmmar Actually it would be nice to have your link as another answer, I think it would provide useful complementary info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can typeset a harpoon, back space and typeset another one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\paronto}{%
  \rightharpoonup\mathrel{\mspace{-15mu}}\rightharpoonup
}

\begin{document}

$f\colon X\paronto Q$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the help of `trimclip` you can make the symbol to have the same dimension as the single headed arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\paronto}{%
  \clippedrightharpoonup\mathrel{\mspace{-15mu}}\rightharpoonup
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\clippedrightharpoonup}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\clipped@rightharpoonup\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\clipped@rightharpoonup}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\mspace{3mu}$}%
  \smash{\clipbox{{\wd\z@} 0pt 0pt {-\width}}{$\m@th#1\rightharpoonup$}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$f\colon X\paronto Q_{\paronto}$

$f\colon X\rightharpoonup Q_{\rightharpoonup}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a rounded stem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\paronto}{%
  \clippedrightharpoonup\mathrel{\mspace{-15mu}}\rightharpoonup
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\clippedrightharpoonup}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\clipped@rightharpoonup\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\clipped@rightharpoonup}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\mspace{6mu}$}%
  \clipbox{0pt 0pt {\dimexpr\width-.5\wd\z@} 0pt}{$\m@th#1\rightharpoonup$}%
  \smash{\clipbox{{\wd\z@} 0pt 0pt {-\width}}{$\m@th#1\rightharpoonup$}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$f\colon X\paronto Q_{\paronto}$

$f\colon X\rightharpoonup Q_{\rightharpoonup}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks quite OK. Sorry for demanding more, but could you very briefly explain differences between `\kern`, `\mkern` and your `\mathrel{\mspace{whatever}}`?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I measured the arrow and found its width is 18mu (within a very small tolerance); `\mspace` is `amsmath` lingo for `\mskip` (essentially the same as `\mkern` in this case), enclosed as a math relation atom so no space will be added.