# How can I create a rectangle symbol?

Tags: symbols

I need to represent symmetries of a a rectangle as a set, and in my text book they do so by using the following notation

> S(SYMBOL-THAT-LOOKS-LIKE-A-RECTANGLE)

I searched everywhere, tried http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html and no luck. So, I came to terms with there not being any rectangle, and the closest I have been able to get is

```
$s\sqsubset\sqsupset$
```

Is there any way I can reduce the spacing between them so they make a better rectangle?

Comment: `\square` from `amssymb`. or `$s\sqsubset\!\sqsupset$`

Comment: \square is like, a square though right? :D (the second one will do btw, that was just what i was after :D)

Comment: You want a rectangle!, what should be the width?

Comment: $s\sqsubset\!\sqsupset$ did the trick! thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is U+25AD (▭) and available as `\hrectangle` in `unicode-math` (if using xelatex or lualatex) or `stix` if using `pdflatex` (and will be available in other font packages that cover the Unicode math blocks)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}

$a \hrectangle b $

\end{document}
```

Comment: For a filled rectangle `\hrectangleblack` of `stix` may be used.

Answer (score 15):

A good occasion for `\ooalign`, one of the best tricks in my toolbox:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\rectangle}{{%
  \ooalign{$\sqsubset\mkern3mu$\cr$\mkern3mu\sqsupset$\cr}%
}}

\begin{document}
$S(\rectangle)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Experiment changing `3mu` for different ratios between width and height.

Comment: What does `ooalign` stands for? (I'm mostly interested in the `oo` since `align` is self explanatory :D)

Comment: @Manuel See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/4427

Comment: I meant the name. Just curiosity. `halign` in some way is “horizontal alignment”, `valign` for “vertical”, but `oo`? “over and over”?

Comment: @Manuel You should ask Donald Knuth.

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\rectangle}{\fboxsep0pt\fbox{\rule{1em}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{1ex}}}
\begin{document}
  $s\rectangle$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
  A$\sqsubset \! \sqsupset$B
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple method would be to use tikzpackage. You can draw each line of the rectangle. It may be tedious at first to use tikz, but it is so much more convenient when you need to modify your image.
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \begin{document}

```
\maketitle


S
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small\sffamily\bfseries, node distance = 0.5cm]
\tikzset{
    mynode/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,draw=black, top color=white, bottom     color=yellow!50,very thick, inner sep=1em, minimum size=3em, text centered},
    myarrow/.style={->, >=latex', shorten >=1pt, thick},
    mylabel/.style={text width=7em, text centered} 
}  
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw,  
    text width=11em, text centered]

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, text width=4em, text badly centered, inner     sep=0pt]

\node[block] (rectangle) [text width=13em] {text_inside_rectangle};  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here, I draw a node. you can specify the dimensions of the rectangle accordingly. And if you want more such rectangles you just have to repeat the '\node[block] (rectangle) [text width=13em] {text_inside_rectangle};  '
 statement. Hope this helps.

Comment: As it is, this is more of a comment rather than an answer. If you actually include the code to draw the rectangle then this would make a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal solution using TikZ will be

```
\newcommand{\rectangle}{\tikz[\draw (0,0) rectangle (3.2mm,2mm);}}
```

A slightly enhanced version is

```
\newcommand{\rectangle}{
    \tikz[line width = 0.52pt, line join = round]{
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (3.2mm,2mm);
    }
}
```

where the first option indicate the line width and the second one makes the borders rounded, which in my opinion, looks better. Hope it helps.