# White vertical rectangle symbol in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

How to make a symbol like Unicode Character 'WHITE VERTICAL RECTANGLE' (U+25AF) in LaTeX?

I tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213848/186257):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
$a \vrectangle b $
\end{document}
```

– it works, but makes my PDF change its look entirely (which is uglier than usual).

I also tried to adapt the `\newcommand` answers from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213841/186257) question, but failed.

**Context**

This symbol is needed to typeset a paper about Communicating Sequential Processes (CSP). According to my professor, this symbol is read as "fetbar" (misspelling of "fat bar") and is used to signify choice by channel. Like this:

> MACHINE = (coinslot.$5 → (tea_button.press → hatch.tea → MACHINE ▭ icetea_button.press → hatch.icetea → MACHINE ) )

(But instead of horizontal white rectangle, should have a vertical one.)

Comment: Just paint it yourself using inline `tikz` or primitives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the first two ideas I came up with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\vrectangleA}{{\ooalign{\lower.3ex\hbox{$\sqcup$}\cr\raise.4ex\hbox{$\sqcap$}}}}

\newcommand*{\vrectangleB}{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{\phantom{l}}}}

\begin{document}

a \vrectangleA\ b

a \vrectangleB\ b

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help. Seems like magic to me :-P

Answer (score 1):

A version that scales in subscripts and superscripts, also changing the line thickness according to the thickness of the fraction line in the corresponding math style (which is stored in `\fontdimen8` of the font in family 3).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\vrectangle}{\mkern1mu\mathpalette\v@rectangle\relax\mkern1mu}
\newcommand{\v@rectangle}[2]{%
  \hbox{%begingroup
  \fboxrule=0.5\fontdimen 8
    \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
    \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
    \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 3
  \fboxsep=-\fboxrule
  \fbox{$\m@th#1\phantom{(}$}%
  }%\endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

$a \vrectangle b_{\vrectangle_{\vrectangle}}$

\end{document}
```

Change the factor `0.5` in front of `\fontdimen` to suit your taste.

You may want to change the type, say by also doing

```
\newcommand{\bvrectangle}{\mathbin{\vrectangle}} % for a binary operation
```

or

```
\newcommand{\rvrectangle}{\mathrel{\vrectangle}} % for a binary relation
```

[image]

Comment: "...according to the _width_ of the fraction line...". Shouldn't _width_ be _thickness_?

Comment: @campa Yes, of course. Although the thickness *can* be called width.

Comment: Ah, British terminology, right? `:-)` I remember some remark in the `booktabs` documentation...

Comment: Sorry to bother, but I've got a (probably dumb) question: `amsmath` is necessary in order to have the scalable `cmex` fonts, i.e. the scalable rule width, right? Without it the three boxes would have the same line thickness. If yes, it might be an important thing to mention.

Comment: @campa Yes, that's completely true. But whenever math is used in a document, `amsmath` is *very* recommended.

Comment: I know, I'm a theoretical physicist `;-)`