# How do I write logical iff symbol?

Tags: symbols, math-operators, stacking-symbols, logic

I'm currently hearing a lecture about formal systems (a computer science lecture).

The lecturer makes a symbol that is written like overlying `<` and `>`:

[image]

Every time when he draws it, he says "genau dann wenn" (German for "if, and only if").

How do I crate this symbol with LaTeX?

Comment: Why not `\iff`? BTW, I've never seen that symbol before.

Comment: @HenriMenke I think he wants to make sure that this does not get confused with the symbol used for equivalence in propositional calculus formulas / predicate logic formulas. But I'm not too sure about it.

Comment: In my experience `\leftrightarrow` would be used.

Comment: I always write "if and only if" or "just when", to minimize confusion. Your symbol would confuse me, because I have never seen it before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And here is more simple definition than @egregs ooalign:

```
\def\gdw{\mathrel{{>}\mkern-13mu{<}}}

$A \gdw B$
```

And it is optical better:

[image: gdm]

Comment: Guess the width? Sorry, I don' buy it. Try with `\usepackage{newtxmath}` and you'll get [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4mcSg.png). Is it “optically better”?

Comment: @egreg If the character is missing in the font then user have to play as font designer and to guess the most optimal look for each font family. This cannot be done by automaton which can do only exactly aligned result, no optical optimal result.

Answer (score 9):

A simple application of `\ooalign`:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Simple version if you don't need it in sub/superscripts
%\newcommand\gdw{\mathrel{\ooalign{$<$\cr$>$\cr}}}

% Fuller version
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gdw}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\@gdw@\relax}}
\newcommand{\@gdw@}[2]{\ooalign{$\m@th#1<$\cr$\m@th#1>$\cr}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$X \gdw Y_{\gdw}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/4427) for a quick course on `\ooalign`. What's the advantage of this complicated looking solution over a seemingly simpler “print >, back up and print <”? That you don't need to guess the width of the symbol, which might change with the font used; with `\ooalign` you don't run the risk of having to compute the width.

If you want to make the inner rhombus smaller, you can add some pushing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gdw}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\@gdw@\relax}}
\newcommand{\@gdw@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1\@gdw@push<$\cr$\m@th#1>\@gdw@push$\cr}}
\newcommand{\@gdw@push}{\mkern2mu}% adjust to suit
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$X \gdw Y_{\gdw}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\gdw}{%
  \mathrel{\mathrlap{>}}% print > with zero width
  \mathrel{\mkern2mu}% some small spacing
  <% print the <
}

\begin{document}
$X \gdw Y_{\gdw}$
\end{document}
```

This produces exactly the same output as the last one (with the 2mu to be adjusted to suit). It is simpler in its aspect, because it uses `\mathpalette` internally. It exploits the fact that TeX inserts no space between consecutive relation atoms.

Comment: The "2mu correction" is font shape dependent. For example for TX math the center of the character is too dark if 2mu is used. From this point of view: it is probably better to design this value individually for each font shape and to implement only the "back up" value, which avoids the need of `\matchoice`.

Answer (score 4):

This is the unicode [U+2AA4](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2aa4/index.htm) named "GREATER-THAN OVERLAPPING LESS-THAN". [Here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2aa4/fontsupport.htm), you may see, which fonts support this symbol and [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%E2%AA%A4%20-%20GREATER-THAN%20OVERLAPPING%20LESS-THAN%20%28U%2B2AA4%29), which fonts on your system do provide it.

The MWE requires Lua- or XeLaTeX. It just shows two fonts I found on my PC. Of course, you should define your preferred version in a `\mathrel`-command.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document} 
\fontspec{Asana Math}\symbol{"2AA4}
\fontspec{XITS Math}\symbol{"2AA4}
\end{document}
```

[image]