# Overlay two symbols. How to make it work as subscript?

Tags: symbols

I am trying to construct a new symbol: a circle with a vertical bar through it.  The following MWE sorta works but doesn't look quite right.

[image: MWE Output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\newcommand{\bcirc}{\mathrel{\ooalign{$\circ$\cr\hidewidth\hbox{$|\mkern 1.9mu$}\cr}}}


\begin{document}

    New symbol $x \bcirc_3 y$ works.
    Also huge version {\huge$x \bcirc_2 y$} works fine.
    In displaymath, compare:
    \begin{align*}
        x \bcirc_1 y &= \pi_{w \bcirc_2 z}  , \\
        x \circ_1 y &= \pi_{w \circ_2 z}  .
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

1. Spacing to the right of the new symbol seems slightly too large I think?
2. More importantly, this symbol does not resize when used as a subscript.  Any tips/modifications I need to make to the definition?

This is based on an answer to [this other tex.SE question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/subseteq-circ-as-a-single-symbol-open-subset/22375#22375)

Comment: `\mathpalette` might be perfect here, as in the solution you linked. By the way, is the *unbalancedness* intended?

Comment: @Manuel: If by unbalancedness you mean the fact that the vertical bar does not go through the circles center, then no, this is not intended.  I didn't see it before when I defined this in another document, it looked right to me there. (The other document uses amsart article class and whole lot more packages.)

Comment: I didn't update the MWE, but used standalone class to produce the image included. Sorry.

Comment: The symbol is siilar to a sans serif Phi, try `\usepackage{tipa,amsmath,graphicx}
\def\bcirc{\scalebox{.7}{\text{\sffamily\textphi}}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `\mathpalette`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bcirc}{\mathrel{\vphantom{|}\mathpalette\do@bcirc\relax}}
\newcommand{\do@bcirc}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $#1\m@th\circ$\cr
    \hidewidth$#1\m@th|$\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    New symbol $x \bcirc_3 y$ works.
    Also huge version {\huge$x \bcirc_2 y$} works fine.
    In displaymath, compare:
    \begin{align*}
        x \bcirc_1 y &= \pi_{w \bcirc_2 z}  , \\
        x \circ_1 y &= \pi_{w \circ_2 z}  .
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `\hidewidth` instead of manual kerning. Centering seems to be good.