# Typeset a 'not equal' symbol, whose slash is reversed (from the upper-left to the bottom-right)

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

The not equal symbol (`≠`), has its slash from the upper-right to the bottom-left. For example:

```
\begin{equation}
    i  \neq  j
\end{equation}
```

Typesets the following:

```
i ≠ j
```

---

How can I obtain a similar symbol, whose slash directionality is reversed (i.e., from the upper-left to the bottom-right, as displayed below)?

[image: A non-canonical 'not equal' symbol, with its slash directionality reversed, as described above.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of `\reflectbox` (as has been pointed out in the comments), but it won't be usable in super- or subscripts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\flipneq}{\mathrel{\reflectbox{$\neq$}}}

\begin{document}
$A \flipneq B \neq C$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\newcommand{\flipneq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\flipneq@\relax}}` and `\newcommand{\flipneq@}[2]{\reflectbox{$\m@th#1{\neq}$}}` (requires the usual `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct this in a similar manner to the methods described in a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108193).

For example, adapting a [prior answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108195/134641) and enhanced via [another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224413/134641), you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rneq}{\mathrel{\vphantom{\neq}\mathpalette\do@rneq\relax}}

\newcommand{\do@rneq}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $#1\m@th=$\cr
    \hidewidth$#1\m@th\backslash$\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \Huge

    \begin{align*}
        i   &   \neq j\\
        \\
        i   &   \rneq j\\
        \\
        \\
        i   &   \neq_{a} j\\
        \\
        i   &   \rneq_{a} j\\
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image: Compiled output of above: depicts i ≠ j, and then a line below with the same but the direction of the slash reversed; then a double line break, followed by the same two lines, except with both symbols having a sub-scripted 'a']

This has the advantage of working fine with most kerning and sub/super-scripting (as shown), and allowing easy adjustment, by changing the spacing within the `\rneq` command.

You also can view this [example on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/pqznxkvjdybg).

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `\flipnot` symbol that can be used like `\not`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\flipnot}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\flipnot@\relax}}
\newcommand{\flipnot@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$#1\not$}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\depth-\dp\z@}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$\m@th#1\not$}}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\fneq}{\flipnot=} % \neq is \not=

\begin{document}

$\neq\fneq$

$a\neq b\fneq c^{\fneq}$

\end{document}
```

[image]