# How to put symbols of equal size on top of each other?

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I would like to put (any) two symbols on top of each other. With `\overset` the one on top is smaller. However, I want them to appear vertically centered and of equal size. How can this be done? Obviously, the following is quite a bad hack:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\ou}[2]{\overset{\text{\large ${#1}$}}{#2}}
\begin{document}
$a\ou{>}{<}0$ or $a\raisebox{-3pt}{\,$\ou{>}{<}$\,}0$ or $a\,{>\atop <}\,0$
\end{document}
```

`\atop` is not too bad, but a) how can I bring the symbols (vertically) closer to each other and b) how can this be defined as a command which takes care of the spacing around operators (`\,`)?

Comment: For `<` and `>` is `\gtrless`, `\lessgtr`, `\lesseqgtr`, `\gtreqless`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol you want to build is already available, so this is just a hint for other similar situations. If you want to set symbols on top of one another, as opposed to *superimpose* symbols over each other, the tool to use is `\ialign`, not `\ooalign` that is handy for the latter case.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\ou}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \vcenter{\offinterlineskip
      \ialign{##\cr$<$\cr\noalign{\kern-1.5pt}$>$\cr}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
$a \ou b$
\end{document}
```

I use `\mathrel` to declare the symbol type, `\vcenter` to make the whole construction centered with respect to the formula axis and `\ialign` with no baselineskip, so I can fine tune the spacing with `\noalign{\kern...}`.

Improvements with `\mathpalette` are possible for making the symbol available in all formula styles.

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg. I just realized: if one of the symbols is much wider than the other, they will not be vertically aligned anymore. Is there a way to get them automatically vertically aligned?

Comment: @MariusHofert This much depends on the shapes of the symbols, so it's not possible to write code that does automatically what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Let me start by saying that the `amssymb` package offers you out of the box the symbol you need as `\lessgtr` (there's also `\grtless`).

If you need, for some reason, to build the symbol by stacking `<` and `>`, one option is to use `\ooalign` with some `\raiseboxes`; the whole construct can then be passed as argument to `\mathrel` to get the proper spacing associated to a relational symbol.

The following code shows a comparisson between your original attempts (first line), the one using `\ooalign` (second line), and the symbol obtained using `\lessgtr` (third line):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand*{\ou}[2]{\overset{\text{\large ${#1}$}}{#2}}

\newcommand\Ou{%
  \mathrel{{\ooalign{\hss\raisebox{-0.5ex}{$>$}\hss\cr\raisebox{0.5ex}{$<$}}}}
}

\begin{document}

$a\ou{>}{<}0$ or $a\raisebox{-3pt}{\,$\ou{>}{<}$\,}0$ or $a\,{>\atop <}\,0$

$a\Ou 0$

$a\lessgtr 0$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, thanks for helping. Do you think this can be adapted to *any* symbols in math mode, not just `>` and `<`?

Comment: @MariusHofert Sure. The approach with `\ooalign` is very versatile and can be used for other symbols too. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/3954 to learn more about `\ooalign`.

Comment: I tried to adapt it (with a 3rd argument for the space): `\newcommand*{\ou}[3]{\mathrel{{\ooalign{\hss\raisebox{#3}{#1}\hss\cr\raisebox{-{#3}}{#2}}}}}` and then called it with `a\ou{>}{<}{0.5ex}0`. Do you know how to get the 'negative sign' to work correctly? One could probably define a length and then set the corresponding negative length correctly, but that seems a bit tedious.

Comment: @MariusHofert this should work: `\newcommand\ou[3]{\mathrel{{\ooalign{\hss\raisebox{-#3}{$#1$}\hss\cr\raisebox{#3}{$#2$}}}}}` and then in your document `$a\Ou{>}{<}{0.5ex} 0$`.

Comment: @MariusHofert Of course, in my definition I assume that you want to stack math symbols (that's why I used `$#1$` and `$#2$`).

Comment: Hi, using this, I obtain `Illegal parameter number in definition of \ou`. Does it work for you?

Comment: @MariusHofert Weird. If I copy paste the definition from my previous comment, the error you mentioned appears. However, if I write the exact same definition from scratch (whitout copy-paste from the comment), it works as expected. Perhaps in the copy-paste process some spurious characters get copied? Try writing the definition from scratch and let me know if it works.

Comment: *excellent*, not it works. There was a spurious space between the `#` and the `3` when it appeared for the second time.

Comment: Sorry, but `\ooalign` is the wrong tool for this.

Comment: @MariusHofert egreg has provided a [`new answer`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251477/3954) below, you should consider using and accepting his answer.

Comment: @egreg Don't be sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

The `stackengine` package provides ready made macros for such things, providing options for vertical placement and separation, as well as horizontal alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
CENTERED STACK:

Specify gap:\def\stacktype{S} 
$x\mathbin{\stackanchor[0pt]{<}{>}}y\mathbin{\stackanchor[-1pt]{<}{>}}z$

Specify baselineskip:\def\stacktype{L} 
$x\mathbin{\stackanchor[6pt]{<}{>}}y\mathbin{\stackanchor[5pt]{<}{>}}z$\medskip

OVER STACK:

Specify gap:\def\stacktype{S} 
$x\mathbin{\stackon[0pt]{<}{>}}y\mathbin{\stackon[-1pt]{<}{>}}z$

Specify baselineskip:\def\stacktype{L} 
$x\mathbin{\stackon[6pt]{<}{>}}y\mathbin{\stackon[5pt]{<}{>}}z$\medskip

UNDER STACK:

Specify gap:\def\stacktype{S} 
$x\mathbin{\stackunder[0pt]{<}{>}}y\mathbin{\stackunder[-1pt]{<}{>}}z$

Specify baselineskip:\def\stacktype{L} 
$x\mathbin{\stackunder[6pt]{<}{>}}y\mathbin{\stackunder[5pt]{<}{>}}z$
\end{document}
```

[image]