# Two-headed version of \xrightarrow

Tags: arrows

I would like a double-headed extensible right-arrow similar to `\xrightarrow` from `amsmath`.

I tried using `\xtwoheadrightarrow` from `extpfeil`, but the result differs from `\xrightarrow` in three respects:

- the arrow head has a different style
- the arrow itself is longer than I would like it
- the text above the arrow is too high

[image]

What's the most straightforward way of achieving a two-headed version of `\xrightarrow`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{extpfeil}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  & \xrightarrow{ABCD} \\
  & \xtwoheadrightarrow{ABCD}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd typeset `\xrightarrow`, back up a little and add `\rightarrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\rightarrowdbl}{\rightarrow\mathrel{\mkern-14mu}\rightarrow}

\newcommand{\xrightarrowdbl}[2][]{%
  \xrightarrow[#1]{#2}\mathrel{\mkern-14mu}\rightarrow
}

\begin{document}
$A \rightarrowdbl B$

$A \xrightarrow[\beta]{\alpha} B$

$A \xrightarrowdbl[\beta]{\alpha} B$

$A \xrightarrowdbl{\text{overlong text}} B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: out of curiosity: Why is it important to treat the \mkern-14mu as a math relation?

Comment: @PeterGuthmann TeX doesn't add space between relations. Well, maybe this is not so relevant here, but that's what's always done (see `\longrightarrow` and similar constructions with `\joinrel`).

Answer (score 8):

Same principle as in egreg's answer, only using the low level command [`\ooalign`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/30280) to place the arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand\dhrightarrow{%
  \mathrel{\ooalign{$\rightarrow$\cr%
  $\mkern3.5mu\rightarrow$}}
}

\newcommand\dhxrightarrow[2][]{%
  \mathrel{\ooalign{$\xrightarrow[#1\mkern4mu]{#2\mkern4mu}$\cr%
  \hidewidth$\rightarrow\mkern4mu$}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
  A \rightarrow B    &&\qquad A \xrightarrow[C]{D} B    &&\qquad A \xrightarrow{\text{long text}} B    & \\
  A \dhrightarrow B  &&\qquad A \dhxrightarrow[C]{D} B  &&\qquad A \dhxrightarrow{\text{long text}} B  &
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think I fractionally prefer this answer, as the text seems to be centered with respect the arrow as a whole. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, I've changed my mind (again) and after some experimentation prefer the positioning of the text in @egreg's answer.

Comment: @Roly Thanks for pointing out the issue with text placement. I've implemented a fix, so that the text is placed correctly above and below the arrow, as well as corrected the spacing before and after the arrows.

Comment: Actually it wasn't obvious to me that there was a problem (I preferred yours originally) but after some experimentation I realised it makes more sense for the text to be centred along the arrow shaft. Thanks. Both answers are good.