# Is there any way to put \ddots in an "x" shape?

Tags: matrices

I tried using this code but ir isn't the result I wanted

```
\newcommand{\xdots}{\ensuremath{{}^\cdot_\cdot}\cdot^\cdot_\cdot}
```

It has to go into this matrix

```
$$B_j\rightarrow\tilde{B}_j=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&\dots&a_{1,j-1}&0&a_{1,j+1}&\dots&a_{1n}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{i-1,1}&\dots&a_{i-1,j-1}&0&a_{i-1,j+1}&\dots&a_{i-1,n}\\0&\dots&0&1&0&\dots&0\\a_{i+1,1}&\dots&a_{i+1,j-1}&0&a_{i+1,j+1}&\dots&a_{i+1,n}\\\vdots&\xdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{n11}&\dots&a_{n,j-1}&0&a_{n,j+1}&\dots&a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}$$
```

Instead of \ddots but the upper and lower dots are smaller in my way, if there isn't a way i will use \ddots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am inspired by the definition of `\ddots` macro and I suggest to define:

```
\def\xdots{\mathinner{\mkern1mu
   \raise.1em\hbox{.}\kern-.33em{\ddots}\kern-.33em\raise.7em\hbox{.}\mkern1mu}}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here, I reflect `\ddots` and superimpose it to create the X shape of dots.

EDITED to address row spacing issue raised by barbara.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\newcommand\xdots{\ooalign{$\ddots$\cr\scalebox{-1}[1]{$\ddots$}}}
\begin{document}
\[
B_j\rightarrow\tilde{B}_j=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&\dots&a_{1,j-1}&0&a_{1,j+1}&\dots&a_{1n}\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{i-1,1}&\dots&a_{i-1,j-1}&0&a_{i-1,j+1}&\dots&a_{i-1,n}\\[5pt]
0&\dots&0&1&0&\dots&0\\[3pt]
a_{i+1,1}&\dots&a_{i+1,j-1}&0&a_{i+1,j+1}&\dots&a_{i+1,n}\\
\vdots&\xdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{n11}&\dots&a_{n,j-1}&0&a_{n,j+1}&\dots&a_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! The same as I did, but with much less work :). What does `\ooalign` do?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik `\ooalign` is a TeX primative for superimposing things.  It is defined on p.356 of the TeXbook.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm on page 74 yet `:)`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/82917) from egreg contains a nice explanation of `\ooalign`, if you don't want to skip 300 pages `;-)`

Comment: irrelevant to answer, but the line with the zeros is really too close to the adjacent lines.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different approach of what you suggested.

The macro `\xdots` first saves a `\ddots` in a box. Then this box is used to place the `\ddots`, and then a negative `\hskip` of the width of the box is applied to return to the original position. Finally, a `\reflectbox` is used to place the other part of the X.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\xdots}{%
\newbox\dotsbox%
\savebox\dotsbox{\(\ddots\)}%
\usebox\dotsbox\hskip-\wd\dotsbox\relax%
\reflectbox{\(\ddots\)}%
}

\begin{document}

$$B_j\rightarrow\tilde{B}_j=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&\dots&a_{1,j-1}&0&a_{1,j+1}&\dots&a_{1n}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{i-1,1}&\dots&a_{i-1,j-1}&0&a_{i-1,j+1}&\dots&a_{i-1,n}\\0&\dots&0&1&0&\dots&0\\a_{i+1,1}&\dots&a_{i+1,j-1}&0&a_{i+1,j+1}&\dots&a_{i+1,n}\\\vdots&\xdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{n11}&\dots&a_{n,j-1}&0&a_{n,j+1}&\dots&a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}$$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain it  with the `\adots` glyph from `yhmath`, superimposed to `\ddots`. Here are two ways:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{mathtools, yhmath}
\usepackage{stackengine} 
\newcommand{\xdots}{\mathrlap{\ddots}{\mkern-1mu\color{red}\adots}}
\newcommand{\sixdots}{\stackMath\stackinset{c}{-0.32ex}{c}{0pt}{ \color{blue}\adots}{ \ddots}}

\begin{document}


\[ \xdots\qquad \sixdots\]%


\end{document}
```

[image]