# Overlap one text string in the middle of the other

Tags: horizontal-alignment

It is possible to overlap and left-align text by using `\rlap{A}BCD`; however, how to overlap A in the middle (exactly centered) of BCD?

Comment: Look for `\ooalign` on the site

Comment: Maybe `\makebox` with a width of zero can help. And a MWE is still possible.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner `\makebox` takes the length input rather than the string BCD.

Comment: `\usepackage{stackengine}...\stackengine{0pt}{BCD}{\kern2pt A}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}` where 2pt is altered to fit your need.

Comment: Here's `\ooalign` from @egreg: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `\makebox` in combination with the `\widthof` command from the `calc` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item ABCD
\item \makebox[0ex][l]{BCD}A
\item \makebox[1ex][l]{BCD}A
\item \makebox[2ex][l]{BCD}A
\item \makebox[3ex][l]{BCD}A
\item \makebox[4ex][l]{BCD}A
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
\item ABCD
\item \makebox[\widthof{BCD}/2-\widthof{A}/2][l]{BCD}A
\item \frame{\makebox[\widthof{BCD}/2-\widthof{A}/2][l]{BCD}}A %for illustration
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\makebox[\widthof{BCD}/2-\widthof{A}/2][l]{BCD}A` you get:

[image]

Side note: Remove the items that include `\makebox` and you get a MWE.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading word usage. I mean how to put A in the _center_ (exactly middle) of BCD.

Comment: @KevinDong Done.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `widthof` is _exactly_ what I need. ;-)

Comment: @KevinDong Then consider accepting the answer and the case is closed.

Answer (score 4):

The default is exactly centered overlap, but fine adjustments may be made with the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\clap[3][0pt]{\stackengine{0pt}{#3}{\kern#1#2}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\begin{document}
\clap{A}{BCD}

\clap[6pt]{A}{BCD}

\clap[-6pt]{A}{BCD}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thanks for pointing out my dyslexia.

Comment: Very neat package (stackengine).

Answer (score 2):

It's easy with `\ooalign`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\overlap}[2]{%
  \leavevmode\begingroup
  \vphantom{#1#2}%
  \ooalign{\hfil#1\hfil\cr\hfil#2\hfil\cr}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\overlap{A}{BCD}

\textsf{\overlap{I}{XXX}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The letter X is not really symmetric, so the result may seem off.

Comment: +1. Better, of course. I would rename `\overlap` to something like `\myOverlap` or `\EgregOverlap` or `\CustomOverlap` to avoid the impression that it is a "standard" command. And I would have guessed that an x is symmetrical :).

Comment: This tex command solution is cool, but `\ooalign` is slightly less intuitive for beginners.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Do you do that with every custom macro you define? Must destroy auto-complete in your editor.

Comment: Maybe I don't define as many custom macros as you :). I am not a programmer and maybe therefore I am a bit conservative in this regard. I get confused by there little things. It's just an idea and not  criticism. I do not understand the argument with the autocomplete. I use Texmaker and do not add custom commands to autocomplete if that's what you mean. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 2):

Your main concern here is to place `A` and `BCD` in a box that has the same size/width. That way you can overlay them and achieve the alignment you're after.

To obtain similarly-sized boxes (width-wise), you can use [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

BCD

\makebox[0pt][l]{\eqmakebox[ABCD]{A}}% or \leavevmode\rlap{\eqmakebox[ABCD]{A}}%
\eqmakebox[ABCD]{BCD}

\end{document}
```

`\eqmakebox` places `<stuff>` with the same `<tag>` in a box that has the maximum width of all `<stuff>`. Individual box `<align>`ment can be specified (`l`eft, `c`enter/default, `r`ight).

Comment: Since [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) uses a `\label`-`\ref`-like system, you'll have to compile twice with every change in the `<stuff>` that influences the maximum width associated with that `<tag>`.

Comment: +1 Never crossed `eqparbox` before (at least I don't remember). Will look into it. So far I normally use `\makebox`and `\phantom` manually etc. Do you know if `Scott Pakin` is also a user here`He maintains a lot of packages on CTAN.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: I haven't seen him around, no. You'll find him on [comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.text.tex) though.

Answer (score 2):

The `\stackinset` command is perhaps simpler to use. Nor correction was necessary for this example, so I left the corresponding arguments empty:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\Large\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\color{Tomato}A}{BCD}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Easy to use. Actually, I am stunned by the tomato color. ;-)

Comment: @Kevin Dong:Never seen tomatoes of this colour? ;o)

Comment: I think the color is better than that of the Rotten Tomatoes. ;-)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: I'd prefer  by far  ‘Cuisse de Nymphe Émue’, but there's no such colour in the color-by-names of  `xcolor`.